# Alternative to vector<bool>

Tags: c++, stl, vector, boolean

As (hopefully) we all know, `vector<bool>` is totally broken and can't be treated as a C array. What is the best way to get this functionality?
So far, the ideas I have thought of are:

- Use a `vector<char>` instead, or
- Use a wrapper class and have `vector<bool_wrapper>`

How do you guys handle this problem? I need the `c_array()` functionality.

As a side question, if I don't need the `c_array()` method, what is the best way to approach this problem if I need random access? Should I use a deque or something else?

Edit:

- I do need dynamic sizing.
- For those who don't know, `vector<bool>` is specialized so that each `bool` takes 1 bit. Thus you can't convert it to a C-style array.
- I guess "wrapper" is a bit of a misnomer. I was thinking something like this:

Of course, then I have to read into a `my_bool` due to possible alignment issues :(

```
struct my_bool
{
    bool the_bool;
};
vector<my_bool> haha_i_tricked_you;
```

Comment: Is there some reason not to use... a C-style array?

Comment: rlbond, do you need dynamic size?

Comment: Ok I'll bite - why do you think vector is ""totally broken" ?

Comment: dammit. where did i read that std::vector is specialized for <bool, std::allocator<bool>> oO vector<bool, my_allocator> won't work either :(

Comment: @Andrew Grant - see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2160.html

Comment: rlbond, you can cast my_bool* to bool* and get a pointer to the the_bool member. that's teh nice things about those cute plain old types, alignment is always in sync with the first member of them

Comment: tho i guess i see what you mean. one can't treat it as a bool array then :(

Comment: @rlbond, are you trying to interoperate with a C-array of C99 _Bool?

Comment: @ribond, it would help to know why you want a vector.  Are you planning to sort these values?  Do you want push and pop?

Comment: Interestingly, `vector<bool>` just caused a data race bug in my code, since I expected different threads to be able to modify different elements in the vector at the same time safely. Solved using `deque<bool>`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) if you don't need the array, yes.

Otherwise use an alternative `vector` that doesn't specialize on `bool`, such as the one in [Boost Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/container/Cpp11_conformance.html#container.Cpp11_conformance.Vector_bool).

Answer (score 26):

That's an interesting problem.

If you need what would have been a std::vector if it was not specialized, then maybe something like that would work fine with your case :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>

class Bool
{
public:

    Bool(): m_value(){}
    Bool( bool value ) : m_value(value){}

    operator bool() const { return m_value; }

    // the following operators are to allow bool* b = &v[0]; (v is a vector here).
    bool* operator& () { return &m_value; }
    const bool* operator& () const { return &m_value; }

private:

    bool m_value;

};




int main()
{
    std::vector<Bool> working_solution(10, false);


    working_solution[5] = true;
    working_solution[7] = true;


    for( int i = 0; i < working_solution.size(); ++i )
    {
        std::cout<< "Id " << i << " = " << working_solution[i] << "(" <<(working_solution[i] ? "true" : "false") << ")" <<std::endl; // i used ? : to be sure the boolean evaluation is correct
    }

    std::sort( working_solution.begin(), working_solution.end());
    std::cout<< "--- SORTED! ---" << std::endl;

    for( int i = 0; i < working_solution.size(); ++i )
    {
            bool* b = &working_solution[i]; // this works!

        std::cout<< "Id " << i << " = " << working_solution[i] << "(" << (working_solution[i] ? "true" : "false") << ")" <<std::endl; // i used ? : to be sure the boolean evaluation is correct
    }

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I tried this with VC9 and it seems to work fine. The idea of the Bool class is to simulate the bool type by providing the same behavior and size (but not the same type). Almost all the work is done by the bool operator and the default copy constructors here.
I added a sort to be sure it react as assumed when using algorithms.

Not sure it would suit all cases. If it's right for your needs, it would be less work than rewriting a vector-like class...

Comment: "we could add bool* operator & () { return &m_value; }" - err. **ISO**: "`sizeof(bool)` is not required to be `1`"

Comment: I would prefer to simply change the `operator bool() const` to an `operator bool&()`. This makes it mirror the behaviour of a simple bool better as it supports assignment etc. in cases such as `v[0] = true;` I really can't see an issue with this change, so may I make the edit?

Answer (score 21):

Depends on your needs. I would go for either `std::vector<unsigned char>`. Writting a wrapper can be fine if you only use a subset of the functionality, else it will become a nightmare.

Comment: `unsigned char` is always a single byte while `uint8_t` might not be supported by the implementation. `uint_fast8_t` could work though if the intent is to make it clear it's a single byte and not a character, but you might as well use `std::byte` then

Answer (score 16):

> How do you guys handle this problem? I need the c_array() functionality.

[`boost::container::vector<bool>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/container/Cpp11_conformance.html#container.Cpp11_conformance.Vector_bool):

> **vector**<**bool**> specialization has been quite problematic, and there have been several unsuccessful tries to deprecate or remove it from the standard. `Boost.Container` does not implement it as there is a superior **Boost.DynamicBitset** solution.
>
> ...
>
> So **boost::container::vector::iterator** returns real bool references and works as a fully compliant container. If you need a memory optimized version of **boost::container::vector**<**bool**> functionalities, please use **Boost.DynamicBitset**.

Comment: Thank you!  I want something that works generically for any T and lets me view it as std::span<T>.  boost::container::vector<T> appears to do what I want.

Answer (score 6):

Consider using a vector< int >. Once you get past compilation and type checking, bool and int are both just machine words (edit: apparently this is not always true; but will be true on many PC architectures). In those cases where you want to convert without a warning, use "bool foo = !!bar", which converts zero to false and non-zero to true.

A vector< char > or similar will use less space, though it also has the potential to take a (very small) speed hit in some circumstances, because characters are less than the machine word size. This is, I believe, the main reason that bools are implemented using ints instead of chars.

If you really want clean semantics, I also like the suggestion of making your own boolean class -- looks like a bool, acts like a bool, but fools the template specialization.

Also, welcome to the club of people who want the vector< bool > specialization dropped from the C++ standard (with bit_vector to replace it). It's where all the cool kids hang out :).

Answer (score 5):

This problem was already [discussed](http://groups.google.ru/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/b8d6dd59dfb295c0/e23e0f606d64550a) on comp.lang.c++.moderated. Proposed solutions:

- your own allocator (based on `std::allocator`) and own vector specialization;
- use `std::deque` (as early was recommended in one of books S. Mayers) - but this not for your requirements;
- make POD `bool` wrapper;
- use something (`char`/`int`/etc) with same size as `bool` instead `bool`;

Also early I saw proposal for standard committee - introduce macro (something like `STD_VECTOR_BOOL_SPECIAL`) to disallow this specialization - but AFAIK this proposal was not implemented in stl implementations and wasn't approved.

It seems that your problem has no ways to do this nicely... Maybe in C++0x.

Answer (score 4):

My preferred workaround is a `vector` of a scoped enum that has an underlying type of `bool`. This gets pretty close to the `vector<bool>` we would have had if the committee hadn't specialised it.

```
enum class switch_status : bool { ON, OFF };

static_assert( sizeof( switch_status ) == 1 );

::std::vector<switch_status> switches( 20, switch_status::ON );

static_assert( ::std::is_same_v< decltype( switches.front() ), switch_status &> );
static_assert( ::std::is_same_v< decltype( switches.back()  ), switch_status &> );
static_assert( ::std::is_same_v< decltype( switches[ 0 ]    ), switch_status &> );
```

You will have your own opinions about the wisdom of embracing casts to/from `bool`:

```
enum class switch_status : bool { OFF = false, ON = true };

static_assert( static_cast< bool          >( switch_status::ON  ) == true               );
static_assert( static_cast< bool          >( switch_status::OFF ) == false              );
static_assert( static_cast< switch_status >( true               ) == switch_status::ON  );
static_assert( static_cast< switch_status >( false              ) == switch_status::OFF );
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplest answer is use `vector<struct sb>` where `sb` is `struct {boolean b};`. Then you can say `push_back({true})`. It seems good.