# Segmentation Fault in prime number sieve

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault

when I run this program while inputting a number greater than 46348, I get a segmentation fault. For any values below it, the program works perfectly. I am using CodeBlocks 8.02 on Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit.
The code is as follows:

```
int main()
{

    int number = 46348;
    vector<bool> sieve(number+1,false);
    vector<int> primes;
    sieve[0] = true;
    sieve[1] = true;

    for(int i = 2; i <= number; i++)
    {
        if(sieve[i]==false)
        {
            primes.push_back(i);
            int temp = i*i;
            while(temp <= number)
            {
                sieve[temp] = true;
                temp = temp + i;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++)
        cout << primes[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possibly off-topic: Are you aware that `vector<bool>` might not be what you expected it to be? See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670308/alternative-to-vectorbool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are on a common architecture, the problem is that the `i*i` calculation overflows. The result can not be stored in a signed 32 bit integer. You can try adding `cout << temp << endl;` after this calculation. In the end it will print:

```
2144523481
2146190929
2147117569
-2146737495
Segmentation fault
```

For the future, you will want to run your code in a debugger. It lets you spot these things more easily. I suspect CodeBlocks offers a graphical debugger. (Otherwise, make sure to compile with `-ggdb` and run your program with `gdb`)

---

Since you are on a 64 bit platform, you might want to use 64 bits unsigned integers to get a greater range. `unsigned long long` (C99, C++0x) is a good way to ask for "the biggest int you've got, that's reasonably cheap". (Even though one `long long` might span two registers, as is the case with a 64 bit datatype on IA32)

---

Alternatively, you can add a check to automatically verify that `number < sqrt(numeric_limits<int>::max())` before entering the loop.

Comment: On many common 64 bit platforms, `unsigned long` is only 32 bit.  `long long` has been a part of standard C for more than a decade now.

Comment: @caf: Thanks. I've learned something new and updated my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`temp` is a 32bit signed integer. In this line:

```
int temp = i*i;
```

it computes `46348*46348 = +2,148,137,104` (maximum value for an signed integer is `+2,147,483,647`)  which creates an overflow (it becomes a negative number) and later you try to access the array with this result:

```
sieve[temp] = true;
```

By accessing the array with a negative number you get the segmentation fault.

---

*(You could change it to `unsigned int` (maximum value `+4,294,967,295`)*

Answer (score 1):

This line: int temp = i*i; causes temp to overflow when i is bigger than 46348, causing the sieve to look for a negative element. Segfault!

Replacing int by unsigned long long will allow you to go much further.