# how to store larger binary numbers in bitset (C++)

Tags: c++, bitset

i m trying to make a program to convert a number into it's binary.

Code:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<algorithm>
    #include<bitset>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int a;
        string k;
        bitset<CHAR_BIT> n;
        cin>>a;
        n=bitset<CHAR_BIT>(a);
        cout<<n<<" ";
            return 0;
   }
```

The program gives wrong answer for 585 as it contains more than 6 binary digits. How can i such greater numbers?

Comment: how big is the largest number you wish to handle?

Comment: Then your bitset needs to be at least 20 bits wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bitset has a fixed number of bits. You specify `bitset<CHAR_BIT>` -- on most systems, CHAR_BIT is 8 so you will have an 8-bit bitset. When you try to stuff a bigger number into the bitset, the most significant bits are discarded.

If you know in advance the largest numbers you will have to deal with, you can specify eg `bitset<16>` or `bitset<32>`. If you don't, you may have to use [some other datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670308/alternative-to-vectorbool).

Answer (score 4):

585 mod 256 = 73 (assuming CHAR_BIT is 8)
73 in base 2 = 0b01001001
[The program does print 01001001](http://www.ideone.com/8BnBH).
I don't see there's anything wrong.

If you want to store the whole range of `a`, the bitset should be declared as

```
bitset<CHAR_BIT * sizeof(a)> n (a);
```