# Why isn't vector<bool> a STL container?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, containers, bitvector

Item 18 of Scott Meyers's book *Effective STL: 50 Specific Ways to Improve Your Use of the Standard Template Library* says to avoid `vector <bool>` as it's not an STL container and it doesn't really hold `bool`s.

The following code:

```
vector <bool> v; 
bool *pb =&v[0];
```

will not compile, violating a requirement of STL containers.

Error:

```
cannot convert 'std::vector<bool>::reference* {aka std::_Bit_reference*}' to 'bool*' in initialization
```

`vector<T>::operator []` return type is supposed to be `T&`, but why is it a special case for `vector<bool>`?

What does `vector<bool>` really consist of?

The Item further says:

```
deque<bool> v; // is a STL container and it really contains bools
```

Can this be used as an alternative to `vector<bool>`?

Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: It was a design mistake in C++98, now retained for compatibility.

Comment: So, I'm also wondering why `std::vector<bool>` shouldn't compile. I also remember it's a specialization.

Comment: @g-makulik, It's not that the use of it won't compile, just that you can't store the address of an element in a pointer to `bool`, since the element doesn't have its own address.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670308/alternative-to-vectorbool

Comment: @chris Ah, I see! Right yes, you can't do that.

Comment: @g-makulik `std::vector<bool> v;` will compile. `&v[0]` will not (taking address of a temporary).

Comment: @Oktalist What is with deque<bool> then ?

Comment: @PrashantSrivastava It's not specialized for `bool` and thus keeps reasonable behaviour.

Comment: `vector<bool>` has a bad rep but not entirely justifiably so: http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool

Comment: Semi-related: [1 bit per bool in Array C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4049156/4975230), if anyone's wondering why you *can* get the reference of a bool in a C style bool array. Note that `bool[]` arrays aren't packed with 1 bit per bool like `vector<bool>` is.

Comment: *"says to avoid vector <bool> as it's not an STL container and it **doesn't really hold bools**."* - that's irritating claim to me. What does it hold then, red herrings? The C++ `bool` type doesn't have standardized implementation, you can't rely on any particular feature of it (in standard portable C++ source), except using it as `bool`, that should work, and that also works with `vector<bool>` well. Its size is undefined and the `vector<bool>` just takes this to another level (no address), to gain particular benefit of size optimization. Recommending general "avoid" is like: "bloat your SW".

Comment: Is this question asking about STL `vector<bool>` or C++ standard library `vector<bool>`?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

For space-optimization reasons, the C++ standard (as far back as C++98) explicitly calls out `vector<bool>` as a special standard container where each bool uses only one bit of space rather than one byte as a normal bool would (implementing a kind of "dynamic bitset"). In exchange for this optimization it doesn't offer all the capabilities and interface of a normal standard container.

In this case, since you can't take the address of a bit within a byte, things such as `operator[]` can't return a `bool&` but instead return a proxy object that allows to manipulate the particular bit in question. Since this proxy object is not a `bool&`, you can't assign its address to a `bool*` like you could with the result of such an operator call on a "normal" container. In turn this means that `bool *pb =&v[0];` isn't valid code.

On the other hand `deque` doesn't have any such specialization called out so each bool takes a byte and you can take the address of the value return from `operator[]`.

Finally note that the MS standard library implementation is (arguably) suboptimal in that it uses a small chunk size for deques, which means that using deque as a substitute isn't always the right answer.

Comment: do we have any other data type for which any other STL container is specialized or explicitly called ?

Comment: Does this apply for C++11 std::array<bool> ?

Comment: @chuckleplant no, `std::array` is merely a templated wrapper around a raw array of `T[n]` with some helper functions like `size()`, copy/move semantics, and iterators added to make it STL-compatible - and (thankfully) it does not violate its own principles to (note my scepticism of these:) 'specialise' for '`bool`'.

Comment: Just a nit pick - the sizeof(bool) isn't necessarily a byte. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897844/is-sizeofbool-defined-in-the-c-language-standard

Comment: Does vector<uint8_t> use same space as vector<uint32_t>? Is there memory padding when using uint8_t in a vector?

Answer (score 35):

The problems is that `vector<bool>` returns a **proxy reference object** instead of a true reference, so that C++98 style code `bool * p = &v[0];` won't compile. However, modern C++11 with `auto p = &v[0];` can be made to compile if `operator&` also [**returns a proxy pointer object**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14061694/819272). Howard Hinnant has written **[a blog post](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool)** detailing the algorithmic improvements when using such proxy references and pointers.

Scott Meyers has a long Item 30 in [**More Effective C++**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163371X) about proxy classes. You can come a long way to **almost** mimic the builtin types: for any given type `T`, a pair of proxies (e.g. `reference_proxy<T>` and `iterator_proxy<T>`) can be made mutually consistent in the sense that `reference_proxy<T>::operator&()` and `iterator_proxy<T>::operator*()` are each other's inverse.

However, at some point one needs to map the proxy objects back to behave like `T*` or `T&`. For iterator proxies, one can overload `operator->()` and access the template `T`'s interface without reimplementing all the functionality. However, for reference proxies, you would need to overload `operator.()`, and that is not allowed in current C++ (although Sebastian Redl [**presented such a proposal**](https://github.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2013/blob/master/thu/overloading_dot.pdf?raw=true) on BoostCon 2013). You can make a verbose work-around like a `.get()` member inside the reference proxy, or implement all of `T`'s interface inside the reference (this is what is done for `vector<bool>::bit_reference`), but this will either lose the builtin syntax or introduce user-defined conversions that do not have builtin semantics for type conversions (you can have at most one user-defined conversion per argument).

**TL;DR**: no `vector<bool>` is not a container because the Standard requires a real reference, but it can be made to behave almost like a container, at least much closer with C++11 (auto) than in C++98.

Answer (score 31):

`vector<bool>` contains boolean values in compressed form using only one bit for value (and not 8 how bool[] arrays do). It is not possible to return a reference to a bit in c++, so there is a special helper type, "bit reference", which provides you a interface to some bit in memory and allows you to use standard operators and casts.

Comment: @PrashantSrivastava `deque<bool>` isn’t specialised so it’s literally just a deque holding bools.

Comment: @PrashantSrivastava `vector<bool>` has a specific template implementation. I guess, other STL containers, such as `deque<bool>`, don't, so they hold bool-s like any other types.

Comment: Here is a questions asking a similar thing in rust where they disallowed single bit booleans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48875251/rust-seems-to-allocate-the-same-space-in-memory-for-an-array-of-booleans-as-an-a

Answer (score 22):

Many consider the `vector<bool>` specialization to be a mistake.

In a paper ["Deprecating Vestigial Library Parts in C++17"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0174r0.html)
There is a proposal to 
**Reconsider vector Partial Specialization**.

> There has been a long history of the bool partial specialization of
>   std::vector not satisfying the container requirements, and in
>   particular, its iterators not satisfying the requirements of a random
>   access iterator. A previous attempt to deprecate this container was
>   rejected for C++11, [N2204](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2204).

---

> One of the reasons for rejection is that it is not clear what it would
>   mean to deprecate a particular specialization of a template. That
>   could be addressed with careful wording. The larger issue is that the
>   (packed) specialization of vector offers an important
>   optimization that clients of the standard library genuinely seek, but
>   would not longer be available. It is unlikely that we would be able to
>   deprecate this part of the standard until a replacement facility is
>   proposed and accepted, such as [N2050](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2050). Unfortunately, there are no such
>   revised proposals currently being offered to the Library Evolution
>   Working Group.

Answer (score 6):

Look at how it is implemented. the STL builds vastly on templates and therefore the headers do contain the code they do.

for instance look at the **stdc++** implementation [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob_plain;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_bvector.h;hb=HEAD).

also interesting even though not an stl conforming bit vector is the **llvm::BitVector** from [here](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/BitVector_8h_source.html).

the essence of the `llvm::BitVector` is a nested class called `reference` and suitable operator overloading to make the `BitVector` behaves similar to `vector` with some limitations. The code below is a simplified interface to show how BitVector hides a class called `reference` to make the real implementation almost behave like a real array of bool without using 1 byte for each value.

```
class BitVector {
public:
  class reference {
    reference &operator=(reference t);
    reference& operator=(bool t);
    operator bool() const;
  };
  reference operator[](unsigned Idx);
  bool operator[](unsigned Idx) const;      
};
```

this code here has the nice properties:

```
BitVector b(10, false); // size 10, default false
BitVector::reference &x = b[5]; // that's what really happens
bool y = b[5]; // implicitly converted to bool 
assert(b[5] == false); // converted to bool
assert(b[6] == b[7]); // bool operator==(const reference &, const reference &);
b[5] = true; // assignment on reference
assert(b[5] == true); // and actually it does work.
```

This code actually has a flaw, try to run:

```
std::for_each(&b[5], &b[6], some_func); // address of reference not an iterator
```

will not work because `assert( (&b[5] - &b[3]) == (5 - 3) );` will fail (within `llvm::BitVector`)

this is the very simple llvm version. `std::vector<bool>` has also working iterators in it. 
thus the call `for(auto i = b.begin(), e = b.end(); i != e; ++i)` will work. and also `std::vector<bool>::const_iterator`.

However there are still limitations in `std::vector<bool>` that makes it behave differently in *some* cases.

Answer (score 2):

This comes from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/

> Vector of bool This is a specialized version of vector, which is used
>   for elements of type bool and optimizes for space.
>
> It behaves like the unspecialized version of vector, with the
>   following changes:
>
> - The storage is not necessarily an array of bool values, but the    library implementation may optimize storage so that each value is
>     stored in a single bit.
> - Elements are not constructed using the allocator object, but their    value is directly set on the proper bit in the internal storage.
> - Member function flip and a new signature for member swap.
> - A special member type, reference, a class that accesses individual    bits in the container's internal storage with an interface that
>     emulates a bool reference. Conversely, member type const_reference is 
>     a plain bool.
> - The pointer and iterator types used by the container are not    necessarily neither pointers nor conforming iterators, although they
>     shall simulate most of their expected behavior.
>
> These changes provide a quirky interface to this specialization and
>   favor memory optimization over processing (which may or may not suit
>   your needs). In any case, it is not possible to instantiate the
>   unspecialized template of vector for bool directly. Workarounds to
>   avoid this range from using a different type (char, unsigned char) or
>   container (like deque) to use wrapper types or further specialize for
>   specific allocator types.
>
> bitset is a class that provides a similar functionality for fixed-size
>   arrays of bits.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question directly. At best, it requires the reader to infer which things explained in this general summary make it non-STL.