# compiler error when pointing to an element of std::vector<bool>?

Tags: c++, vector

Trying to use `std::vector<bool>` I have a compiler error that is very surprising to me.

In short taking the address of an element of a `std::vector<unsigned char>` and assigning it to a `unsigned char` pointer:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> test(10);
unsigned char *pb = &test[0];
```

works perfectly well, while trying to do the same thing with a `std::vector<bool>` results in a compiler error:

```
int main() {

    std::vector<bool> test(10);
    bool *pb = &test[0];    // line 4, compile error

    return 0;
}
```

On Visual Studio, it says something like:

```
std::vector bool cannot convert std::_Vb_reference<_Alloc> * to bool *
```

while codepad ([see example at http://codepad.org/vaiN3iEq](http://codepad.org/vaiN3iEq)) says:

```
cc1plus: warnings being treated as errors
In function 'int main()':
Line 4: warning: taking address of temporary
Line 4: error: cannot convert '__gnu_norm::_Bit_reference*' to 'bool*' in initialization
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

I thought both `bool` and `unsigned char` were internally the same (just a 1 byte type, with some compiler stuffs to enforce `bool` to allow only true/false values). But I was not expecting such problem! Any idea why?!

Note that I know of bitsets and am not interested in using them here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why vector<bool> not a STL container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794569/why-vectorbool-not-a-stl-container)

Comment: On the other hand, I'd prefer using iterators rather than address of operators. Using iterators gives a better scalable design.

Comment: @YogeshSajanikar this is quite out of topic here, but I first see iterators as unreadable (between a `for (int i=0; i<10; i++) a[i]=0;` and `for (std::vector<my_type>::iterator it=a.begin(); it!=a.end(); ++it) *it=0` , the first one is *much* more readable) and I guess they incur a performance hit (especially in debug with all the different checks etc.) which is a pain for something as simple as putting/accessing a value at a given location in memory. They may become useful for other contains (std::map etc), but for std::vectors, I just hate them. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `bool` and `unsigned char` typically take the same amount of memory on their own, but that does not make `vector<bool>` and `vector<unsigned char>` the same!

`vector<bool>` is given very, *very* special treatment by the standard in order to pack elements as close as possible (which someone in the 1990s thought would be clever, since a `bool` has one of only two states), and the result is what you've seen: its elements are non-addressable.

Avoid!

Comment: thanks! I didn't mean the vectors to be the same and I can still do double* v = (double*) my_unsigned_char_vector[0] and that would compile. What do you mean by "packing elements as close as possible" ? These are not bitsets, and the closest possible way to arrange series of 8bits variables is to put them contiguously...

Comment: @WhitAngl The standard requires that `vector<bool>` is a bitset. So its `operator[]` returns a proxy object (since you can return a reference to a bit field). And you cannot take the address of that proxy in the expression you have since it is an rvalue.

Comment: @WhitAngle `vector<bool>` is a specialization designed to allow bits to be packed together. That is, it might internally store 8 bit `char`s and use each bit as a `bool`.

Comment: @WhitAngl: Why do you assert "these are not bitsets"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was assuming so, but was apparently wrong. I thought of std::vector as just a plain array of elements, and that seems to be the case for all other types.

Comment: @WhitAngl the specialization of `std::bool` is recognized as a mistake by nearly everyone now. Unfortunately you can't go back in time and revoke it, it's an accepted part of the standard.

Comment: @WhitAngl: Yep. It's just for bool.

Comment: @MarkRansom: There's no such thing as `std::bool`.

Comment: LightnessRacesinOrbit and @WhitAngl, argh! Naturally I meant to say `std::vector<bool>`. Next time I'll be careful not to any words out.