# Why for_each cannot choose the correct print here

Tags: c++, templates

I write a print template function which prints `"True"` or `"False"` for bool type value.

I tried to apply it to the `for_each` algorithm but it does not work.

The output is still `0` or `1`. It seems the template specialization does not work in `for_each`. How can this happen?

How can I make the code work as expected?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void _print(const T& i)
{
    cout<<i<<endl;
}
template <>
void _print<bool>(const bool& i)
{
    if (i == 0)
        cout<<"False"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"True"<<endl;
}

class print
{
public:
  template <typename T>
  void operator()(const T& val) const { _print(val); };
};

int main()
{
  auto even = [&](int i)->bool{return (i%2==0);};
  srand(time(NULL));
  vector <int> test(3);
  generate(test.begin(),test.end(),[]()->int{return rand()%100;});
  for_each(test.begin(),test.end(),print());
  vector <bool> flag(3);
  transform(test.begin(),test.end(),flag.begin(),even);
  for_each(flag.begin(),flag.end(),print());

  return 0;

}
```

The output is:

```
34
23
3
1
0
0
```

but I expect:

```
34
23
3
True
False
False
```

Comment: It's not an error message, read the question more closely.

Comment: Is there a really good reason you need this instead of just `std::cout << std::boolalpha << yourbool;`?

Comment: I'm so sick of SO answers like Jerry's.  Did you ever think, maybe, the real situation is more complex and this is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?  Can't we give users the benefit of the doubt and assume they *actually want an answer to the question* instead of a suggestion to do something else?  This is an interesting question about template specialization rules in C++.  Who cares if there's a better way to implement the toy example?

Comment: @japreiss, yes we can, when there is a K letter in user's reputation score :)

Comment: The problem is that `operator[]` and likewise of `std::vector<bool>[]` [do no return a `bool&`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool).

Comment: @Basilevs Point taken, but I wish more users were aware of your rule because I still get these answers at 4.5k.

Comment: Suggested Reading:http://stackoverflow.com/a/17794965/1870232

Comment: @japreiss: 1) It was a comment, not an answer. 2) It was in the form of a question, and honestly was intended as a question, not sarcasm. Can't we give users the benefit of the doubt, and assume they actually want to accomplish what they seem to be trying to accomplish and help them out instead of answering a question in a way that happens to interest us instead of helping them? And while high rep may be bad, I try not to hold it against people, and try to help out when I can even if their rep is much higher than any sane person's could possibly be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The evil part of `std::vector<bool>`.
`vector<bool>::reference` is not `bool` as you may expect but a proxy.

You may add this extra overload (or specialization if you prefer):

```
void _print(const vector<bool>::reference& i)
{
    _print<bool>(i);
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/LTnmeh)

Comment: So it is. I am trying to introduce functional programming ideas into C++ and use algorithms like high-order functions. Are all the containers have such wrappers like vector does? For example, vector<int>::reference is not int either?

Comment: @iceiceice: `vector<bool>` is the only standard "container" that doesn't behave like a container. All the others (other containers, and other specialisations of `vector`) define `reference` to be a regular reference to the value type, so will work with your example code.

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` is one of the weirdest decisions ever. how could they not realize it's a bad idea? Why didn't they just make a `packed_bool_vector` type?

Answer (score 4):

The trouble is that `vector<bool>` is not a container of `bool`. Instead, it packs multiple "boolean" values into each byte of its storage, so that it's not possible to obtain a reference to any `bool` value. Instead, dereferencing an iterator gives a "proxy" object of type `vector<bool>::reference`, which behaves like a reference to `bool` in some, but not all, circumstances.

In this case, that's not good enough; your specialisation of `_print` expects a genuine `const bool&` reference, but `_print` instead passes an object of the `reference` type, from which the generic template is deduced.

You could support `vector<bool>` as a special case by adding an overload for this type:

```
void _print(std::vector<bool>::reference r) {_print(bool(r));}
```

(By the way, you shouldn't be using [reserved names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783) like `_print`)