# variable declared by auto sometimes is by reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I just tested this piece of code.

```
vector<bool> v(5, true);
if(v.back())cout<<"====="<<endl;
auto b1 = v.back();
b1 = false;
cout<<&b1<<endl;
if(v.back())cout<<"*********"<<endl;
```

My questions are following:

1. "*********" (no quotes) doesn't appear in the output, why the variable declared by
   `auto` is changing the bool vector `v`?
2. I understand that `vector<bool>` is not a standard STL container, and addressing the element of it by `&v[4]` won't work(since you can not address the address of a bit), if `b1` is declared by a reference to `v.back()`, why I can address `b1` by `&b1`?
3. In what cases `auto` has this kind of behavior? Does `auto c1 = v.begin()` and later doing `c1 = (++v.begin())` will change `v.begin()`?

Comment: Be aware that `vector<bool>` is not a `vector`.

Comment: `back()` return a reference, therefor I think auto will prefer declare it as reference. if you want to be sure test it with class and check if the copy constructor had been called.

Comment: @SHR: Uh... what? `auto x = whatever;` always means `x` *is not* a reference.

Comment: `auto` follows the rules of template argument deduction. `I understand that vector<bool> is not a standard STL container` What is a "standard STL" container? It's either part of the standard library, or it's part of the STL. And it *is* a standard container, the specialization just happens to have different semantics.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is vector<bool> not a STL container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794569/why-is-vectorbool-not-a-stl-container)

Comment: Ok, I tested it with a class and the copy constructor was called, means the auto is NOT reference even though the function return reference.

Comment: @SHR Yes, `auto` will discard both `const` and `&`. `decltype(auto)` (C++14) preserves both - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/283d78b63e6627c3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`std::vector<bool>`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) is a failure in the standard library, a `vector<T>` which *is not a container of `T`s*.

Thus, it has significantly different behavior from all other instantiations of `vector`.

The specific wart you stumbled over is that it's member-type `reference` is a **proxy class representing a reference to a single `bool`**.

Which means that `auto`, which **never** deduces as a reference, deduced as that proxy-class, will behave **as if it was a reference**.

`&v[4]` won't work for getting a pointer to the `bool` at index 4, because `vector<bool>` is not a container of `bool` and the index-operator also returns those proxy-classes.

Naturally, `vector<bool>` has really special iterators which allow iterating over the bit-set, so using iterators only has the handicap that dereferencing an iterator also returns a proxy.

Comment: what do you mean by "a `vector<T>` which is not a container of `T`s"? Are you referring to only `vector<bool>` here?

Comment: @user2345484: Yes. I thought that was unambiguous.