# operator[] compiler error and warning

Tags: c++

Probably it's cause i didn't sleep all the night...but can someone explain me why the first operator[] (the const one) generates a warning in MSVC 2010 saying that i'm returning the address of a temorary variable, and the second operator[] (the non-const one) produces a compiler error stating: 'return' : cannot convert from 'std::_Vb_reference<_Alloc>' to 'bool &' ?!?!?

Thanks a lot to everyone will waste time on my question.

```
    class ReqAtts
    {
    public:
        const bool& operator[](size_t ii) const
        {
            return _atts[ii];
        }

        bool& operator[](size_t ii)
        {
            return _atts[ii];
        }

    private:
        std::vector<bool> _atts;

    };
```

Comment: One thing that I noticed immediately is that in the second function your parameter is "att" but you're indexing "ii" into the array.

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` is actually treated as a special case in C++. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17794965) should help explain why.

Comment: thanks a lot to huu for the useful link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::vector<bool>` is space efficient in most implementations (g++, MSVC): every item may be stored as a single bit, not as bool. You can read more here: [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool)

You have 2 options:

1. Use `std::vector<unsigned char>` (or other integer type) instead of `std::vector<bool>`.
2. Use `std::vector<bool>::reference` as return type for `operator[]` as follows:

   ```
   class ReqAtts
   {
   public:
       std::vector<bool>::const_reference operator[](size_t ii) const
       {
           return _atts[ii];
       }

       std::vector<bool>::reference operator[](size_t ii)
       {
           return _atts[ii];
       }

   private:
       std::vector<bool> _atts;

   };
   ```

Comment: considering that the _atts vector is static (must have always the same dimension...nine, it's quite small) the best option is to use a good old c array. Anyway, your solutions are good as well :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Change Parameter att to ii , it will work

```
class ReqAtts
    {
    public:
        const bool& operator[](size_t ii) const
        {
            return _atts[ii];
        }

        bool& operator[](size_t ii)
        {
            return _atts[ii];
        }

    private:
        std::vector<bool> _atts;

    };
```