# for_each in place modification with lambda of vector<bool>

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

When I try to use `for_each` to change vector in place:

```
vector<bool> sub_accs_ind(vec_ids_.size());
std::for_each(sub_accs_ind.begin(), sub_accs_ind.end(), [](bool& b){ b = false; });
```

**It results in error** `/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:4417:14: error: no match for call to ‘(main(int, char* const*)::__lambda3) (std::_Bit_iterator::reference)’
  __f(*__first);`

Could you please guide me about what is wrong here?

Comment: why not using fill constructor in your case ? `vector<bool> sub_accs_ind(vec_ids_.size(), false);` is enough to have all elements to `false`

Comment: And also, what you need is [`transform`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/), not `for_each`

Comment: Reference type of vector<bool> is not a bool, but a proxy class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`std::vector<bool>` is not a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794569/why-is-vectorbool-not-a-stl-container) !

Its iterators don't return a `bool&`, but a proxy instance. In C++11, you have to name its type explicitly:

```
std::for_each(
    sub_accs_ind.begin(),
    sub_accs_ind.end(),
    [](decltype(sub_accs_ind)::reference b){ b = false; }
);
```

C++14 would allow you to declare the parameter as `auto&&` to accomodate both real references and proxies.

Comment: I want to ask you,  `transform(sub_accs_ind.begin(), sub_accs_ind.end(), sub_accs_ind.begin(),  [](bool b){ return false; });`, does it also really change that value?

Comment: @kaitian521 yes, it will work as expected. Two proxies will be used, one for getting the `bool` for your parameter, and one to store the return value back into the vector.

Comment: this make sense, bitset use  1/8 storage than `vector<bool>`, but sometimes readability is more important than efficiency