# why the size of two vector<bool> bVec = { true,false,true,false,true}; vector<char> cVec = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' }; are different?

Tags: c++, vector, std

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
bool a;
char c;
int main() {

    vector<bool> bVec = { true,false,true,false,true};
    vector<char> cVec = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' }; 
    cout<<sizeof( bVec );cout<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof( cVec );
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(a);
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(c);

    return 0;
}
```

When i compile this code i get size of cVec as 20 and size of bvec as 12 . but why the sizes are different?

Comment: `std::vector< bool >` is a special kind of.. animal. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794569/why-is-vectorbool-not-a-stl-container

Answer (score 0):

[`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) is a special case of `std::vector` which stores the data in a space-efficient manner and returns proxy objects instead of `bool&` to manipulate the data. As such, it'll generally have different member data then a normal `std::vector`, hence the size difference.