# Is it possible to alias a value of std::vector<bool> in a different place of code?

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors, reference, stdvector

```
vector<int> vec({1, 1, 2, 1});

int *some_int = &vec[2];
*some_int = 1;
```

Duh. So simple code. And it works. So now let's try bools instead:

```
vector<bool> vec({false, false, true, false});

bool *some_bool = &vec[2];
*some_bool = false;
```

No luck. The compiler spits out errors ([ideone](https://ideone.com/pLWq6v)):

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:8:26: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
  bool *some_bool = &vec[2];
                          ^
prog.cpp:8:26: error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<bool>::reference* {aka std::_Bit_reference*}’ to ‘bool*’ in initialization
```

Maybe let's try references?

```
vector<bool> vec({false, false, true, false});

bool &some_bool = vec[2];
some_bool = false;
```

No luck either ([ideone](https://ideone.com/5z5QFb)):

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:8:25: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘bool&’ from an rvalue of type ‘bool’
  bool &some_bool = vec[2];
                    ~~~~~^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/vector:65:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_bvector.h:80:5: note:   after user-defined conversion: std::_Bit_reference::operator bool() const
     operator bool() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
```

Dang. Is it impossible to store the reference or pointer to a member of `std::vector<bool>` in a different place of code?! I need this for my data structure.

How to fix this issue? Is switching from `std::vector<bool>` to `std::vector<int>` the only option?

Comment: Read: [Why is vector<bool> not a STL container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794569/why-is-vectorbool-not-a-stl-container). `std::vector<bool>` is implemented differently than the rest of the  STL containers.

Comment: `vector<char>` is a better option.  It is faster than `vector<bool>` and requires less space than `vector<int>`.