# Valgrind showing unexpected output in C++ code

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, valgrind, stdvector

In the beginning of a C++ code, I initialize a vector of 1000000(a million) bool type data. However, in valgrind, the maximum heap + stack usage is shown 200Kb. Given that a Bool is 1 Byte, shouldn't it be 1 Mb ?

Is there an optimization that I don't realise ? Or am I missing something ?

Thanks is advance.

I use a Ubuntu64 16.04 system. Compiling the code without `-O` parameter.

**Edit:** The code can be simplified to this,

```
vector<bool> * isPrime;
int main(){
    isPrime = new vector<bool>(1000000, true);
}
```

**Edit2:** It seems there was an optimization that I don't realise (which is stated in the comments). Thanks.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17794569/1896169

Comment: and .. where and how is the bool type is created, allocated?  you need to provide your code. It could be static, it could be packed, ..

Comment: @Justin I couldn't find such a knowledge, using what I asked here. But it seems the answer, thanks.

Comment: vector<bool> is packed with 1 bit per bool.

Comment: `vector<bool>` is such a weird lil' guy it gets its own page on cppreference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool

Comment: So, why the C language tag?  Your post title says C++, your post discusses C++.  So where do you discuss the C language?

Comment: BTW, the C language does not have `std::vector`.  I recommend you figure out which language you are programming in.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That was to reach more people that might be checking the C tag and not C++, and still know the answer. I'll remove it if it is unsuitable or irritating

Comment: @MaxPaython Don't worry, *plenty* of people check the C++ tag...

Answer (score 0):

Compiling the code without -O parameter is equal to -O0, and the -O0 does not mean no optimization. 
You can see the define of gcc optimization in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

In the case, the size same as -Os, and if you use -O1 or higher, the compiler does not use bit vector, in the other words, each bool varaible occupy 1 byte; otherwise the compiler choose bit vector (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/)