# Using std::transform to make a vector of pair

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I would like to create a `vector` of pairs starting from a pair of `vector`s. For example, if `A` is `std::vector A = [1 0 1]` and `B` is `std::vector B = [0 1 0]`, I want a structure `std::vector C = [1 0, 0 1, 1 0]` where `C_i = std::pair(A_i,B_i)`.

I would avoid `for` loop through the two vector, so I'm looking for few lines code like `std::transform()`.

I tried the following code:

```
std::vector<bool> boolPredLabel(tsLabels.size()); 
std::vector<bool> boolRealLabel(tsLabels.size());
std::vector<std::pair<bool,bool>> TrPrPair(tsLabels.size());
std::transform(boolRealLabel.begin(), boolRealLabel.end(), boolPredLabel.begin(), TrPrPair.begin(),std::make_pair());
```

This lead me to a compiler error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘make_pair()’
std::transform(boolRealLabel.begin(), boolRealLabel.end(), boolPredLabel.begin(), TrPrPair.begin(),std::make_pair());
...
note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
std::transform(boolRealLabel.begin(), boolRealLabel.end(), boolPredLabel.begin(), TrPrPair.begin(),std::make_pair());
```

The message is clear, but I don't know what pass to the binary operator. I have to admit that I don't have a clear understanding of `std::transform()` and I've just use it with functor.

Comment: You need to give the template types for `make_pair`. `std::transform(... , std::make_pair<bool, bool>);` https://ideone.com/i9aV3Y

Comment: @RetiredNinja You should post that as an answer, it's better than mine.

Comment: @lubgr Nah, but you may incorporate that into yours. I was surprised it worked too. :)

Comment: [boost::make_zip_iterator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/compute/doc/html/boost/compute/make_zip_iterator.html) might interest you.

Comment: @lubr Thanks for the useful answers. The problem is solved but I still confused about the binary operation of make_pair. How can I check that a specific function object or template function has the appropriate signature function?

Comment: Good question. You can only figure it out from context and docs. In this case: "The types Type1 and Type2 must be such that objects of types InputIt1 and InputIt2 can can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to Type1 and Type2 respectively.  [...]" So its all about dereferencing the iterators. For two `std::vector<bool>` (input) and a `std::vector<std::pair<bool, bool>>` (output), the input derereferences to something `bool`-like and the output to `std::pair<bool, bool>`. Hence the signature `std::pair<bool, bool> f(bool, bool)`or `std::pair<bool, bool> f(const bool&, const bool)`.

Comment: Also note that `std::vector<bool>` is a bit special here, as it's a template specialization that stores a compact form of a boolean representation. This is commonly understood as a design mistake. If you're interested in some more details, see e.g. [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794569/why-is-vectorbool-not-a-stl-container).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The binary operation you pass in doesn't make any sense. `std::make_pair` is a function template taking two arguments, so neither can you invoke it without these two arguments, nor can it be instantiated like a function object to be passed to `std::transform`.

Instead, you can explicitly instantiate `std::make_pair` for the template types in question and pass this as to the algorithm (@RetiredNinja pointed that out but apparently felt too lazy to write an answer):

```
std::transform(boolRealLabel.cbegin(), boolRealLabel.cend(),
    boolPredLabel.cbegin(), TrPrPair.begin(), std::make_pair<bool, bool>);
```

Two other options commonly seen are a lambda,

```
std::transform(boolRealLabel.cbegin(), boolRealLabel.cend(), boolPredLabel.cbegin(),
    TrPrPair.begin(), [](bool a, bool b){ return std::make_pair(a, b); });
```

or a pointer to a function

```
std::pair<bool, bool> toPair(bool a, bool b)
{
    return std::make_pair(a, b);
}

std::transform(boolRealLabel.cbegin(), boolRealLabel.cend(),
    boolPredLabel.cbegin(), TrPrPair.begin(), toPair);
```

And for completeness, [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) on `std::transform` and its binary operation argument (only relevant to the overload that acts on two input ranges):

> **binary_op** - binary operation function object that will be applied.
>
> The signature of the function should be equivalent to the following:
>
> ```
> Ret fun(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
> ```