# How are bools stored in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, boolean

The size of a bool is claimed to be 1 byte using this command:

```
printf("%ld\n", sizeof(bool));
```

But this doesn't seem very efficient. So how are bools stored in memory?

Will the OS search for other bools and store up to 8 bools in a byte, will each bool be stored in a single byte, resulting in 7 unused bits or are they stored differently?

Comment: The answer depends a lot on the compiler and system.
I guess you can find your answer by reading about padding/aligment of c++ compilers, wikipedia talks about it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Comment: The smallest piece of memory that can be addressed is a byte, so packing Booleans creates other problems that are likely to be less efficient in terms of execution time. [`vector<bool>` helps illustrate some of these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17794965/10077).