# How can I distinguish between access of and assignment to index of array?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, dynamic-arrays

I'm writing a dynamic array class.
I've overloaded the `operator[]` to access the pointer containing the data in my array. Also in my class is a member `size` denoting the number of objects in the array. I need to be able to add elements by assigning them via `A[i]` as well as add to front or end using member functions. The problem is that when assigning using `A[i] = x`, I don't know to increment `size`. Is there a way to distinguish whether the [] operator is being used on the left side of = as opposed to simply accessing that index? I've included a simplified version of my implementation.

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
class Array
{
    public:
        [constructors, destructor];
        int& operator[](int index);
        [addToFront(),addToBack(), etc.]
    private:
        int size;     // holds the number of objects in the array
        int capacity;
        int* arr;     // ptr to the data in the array
}

int& Array::operator[](int index)    // overloaded array access operator
{
    return arr[index]; // simplified version of what I use
}

int main()
{
    Array A(6);    // initialize capacity using parameterized constructor
    A.addToFront(15); // addToFront() is able to increment size inside of its function
    A[1] = 10;    // How can I know that I am adding a new object to the array
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of returning `int&`, return some sort of proxy/wrapper that overloads `operator=`. Not sure this is a good idea though, [it's easy to get into a horrendous mess that works almost but not *quite* like a normal container.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17794569/1171191)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a proxy object. You can overload an `operator =` for these objects and do more complicated stuff like incrementing `size` within that member function. Example:

```
class Array
{
   // Rest as before...

   struct Proxy {
     Array& ref;
     int pos;

     Proxy& operator =(int n)
     {
        ref.arr[pos] = n;
        ++ref.size;

        return *this;
     }
   };

   Proxy operator[](int index);
};
```

The implementation of `operator[]` would then be

```
Array::Proxy Array::operator[](int index)
{
   return Proxy{*this, index};
}
```

and the usage as you showed in the exemplary snippet.