# error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘bool&’ to an rvalue of type ‘bool’

Tags: c++, matrix, boolean, c++17

I'm creating my own Matrix Class.
When it comes to the "at" function used to change the value of a certain element, I have this.

```
T & at(unsigned int raw, unsigned int col)
{
    return (_matrix.at(index(raw, col)));
}
```

knowing that

```
std::vector<T>  _matrix;
```

It works perfectly for all types expect for booleans.
I'm not able to do this operation.

```
matrix.at(1, 1) = true;
```

Which is weird because I have the same implementation as std::vector "at" function, which works with booleans.

Any ideas ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::vector<bool>` is special from all other `std::vector` specializations.

Its `.at` member function does not return a reference to `bool`, but a proxy object that can be assigned to and converted to `bool`. Neither the proxy object, nor the converted `bool` (which is a prvalue) can be bound to a `bool&` as you try to do in the `return` statement.

You must handle the case `T = bool` in a special way, e.g. by forbidding it for your matrix class or by using `std::vector<char>` instead of `std::vector<bool>` when your `T` is `bool`:

```
using U = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, bool>, char, T>;

std::vector<U>  _matrix;
```

and then return `U&` instead of `T&` wherever you return references. (This requires `#include<type_traits>` and C++17 in this form, but can be adapted to C++11.)

or by using a wrapper around `bool`, such as

```
struct A {
    bool b;
};
```

that you store in the vector instead of `bool`, so that you can still return references to the `bool` member properly,

or, if you intend to use the packed storage mechanism which differentiates `std::vector<bool>` from all other `std::vector` specializations, you can return the proxy object from your `.at` method and basically introduce the same special case that `std::vector` has for your matrix class, but then you will need to take care of the special case everywhere in your matrix class:

```
decltype(auto) at(unsigned int raw, unsigned int col)
{
    return _matrix.at(index(raw, col));
}
```

(removing the parentheses in the return statement is important in this case and requires C++14) or

```
std::vector<T>::reference at(unsigned int raw, unsigned int col)
{
    return _matrix.at(index(raw, col));
}
```

It is very unfortunate that `std::vector<bool>` is special in that way. Read more about this e.g. in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794569/why-is-vectorbool-not-a-stl-container) and on the cppreference.com page for [`std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool).