# Inconsistency in range based for loop?

Tags: c++

Why does

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
for (int& e : v){
    e = 5;
    std::cout << e << std::endl;
}
```

compile fine, while

```
std::vector<bool> v2{false, false, false};
for(bool& e : v2){
    if(e){
        std::cout << "True\n";
    }
}
```

creates a compile error

```
error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'bool' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'std::__1::__bit_iterator<std::__1::vector<bool, std::__1::allocator<bool> >, false, 0>::reference' (aka 'std::__1::__bit_reference<std::__1::vector<bool, std::__1::allocator<bool> >, true>')
```

The only thing that changes is the type from int to bool?

Comment: Yes, [`vector<bool>` is special](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794569/why-isnt-vectorbool-a-stl-container).

Comment: Actually, you changed a few things between the two.  First: `e=5`, second: `if(e)`.  First: `cout << e`, second: `cout << "True\n"`.  I don't think that matters, but just noting because you said *The only thing that changes is the type from int to bool?*

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst Not `std::bitset`, no. Its length must be known at compile-time.