# Is it possible to store (0,1)-matrix with single bits rather than bool?

Tags: c++, bitmap, bit-manipulation, sparse-matrix

I need to store fairly large size (1M x 1M) square matrices on a limited memory device. The matrices consist of elements only "1" and "0".

I have read that bool could save 1/0 ( or true/false) but that is also 8 bits storage.So I could have stored 8 times larger size if I could store the values in a single bit.

Instead of going with multidimensional storage I chose to store matrices in single dimension matrix and accesing elements via `matrix[row*N + column]` where `size = N * N`

I have a representation below to explain stuff better

```
+ = 1
o = 0
```

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5
0 + o + o o o
1 o + + + o +
2 o o + o + o
3 + o o o o o
4 o o + + o 1

is converted to std::vector<unsigned char> matrix = {1,0,1,0,0,0,...}
```

I chose the unsigned char to store 1 & 0s and have 8 bits of minimum size in c++
I have the following code as a starting point:

```cpp
 int each_row;
 int row_val;
  for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
      
      unsigned char val = matrix[row * N + col];
      each_row = each_row + to_string(val);
      
    }

    row_val = std::stoi(each_row, nullptr, 2); // to int
```

so my question is how can I store values in each row/col in a single bit of a char to compress data ?

Now each value of `val = 0b00000001 or 0b00000000` I want to make use of all bits like the first row and second row combined to be stored as(due to size lower than 8) `0b10100001`

Comment: This actually is what [std::vector<bool>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) does.

Comment: ...but consider its downsides. most importantly, not necessarily contiguous and `std::vector<bool>::reference` (eg returned by `operator[]`) is actually not `bool&`, though that just follows from the requirement of not storing `bool`s

Comment: Its downsides are overrated. Any decent implementation it'll be contiguous (and probably doesn't matter if its not). `operator[]` not returning a `bool&` is not an issue almost all of the time, and can be worked around if it ever is. If you need the packing its probably the right one to use.

Comment: @MikeVine I didnt want to scare OP away from it, just save them from surprises that they might encounter at some point. Funnily I didn't find a good duplciate, but many Q&As about not using it

Comment: 1M x 1M bits on a device with limited memory doesn't sound good. I get that to 125 GB. Perhaps a sparse matrix of some kind would be an option. How much memory is "limited memory"?

Comment: Limited memory these days could mean anything. Ted and I are likely used to measurements in K when we hear limited, but these days embedded devices with gigabytes of RAM aren't that uncommon. That said I'd still expect many to balk at or start thrashing if you took 1/8 GB.

Comment: Does it have to be _super fast™_? You could keep the actual matrix data in a file instead.

Comment: Following Ted Lyngmo comment, can you define "limited memory"? How large will your matrix be? How many ones? Can you run length encode it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what `std::vector<bool>` is for.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>


int main()
{
  std::string each_row;
  int row_val;
  int N = 8;
  std::vector<bool> matrix(N*N);
  for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < N; col++) {
      
      unsigned char val = matrix[row * N + col];
      each_row = each_row + std::to_string(val);
      
    }
    row_val = std::stoi(each_row, nullptr, 2); // to int
  }
}
```

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool):

> `std::vector<bool>` is a possibly space-efficient specialization of
> `std::vector` for the type `bool`.
>
> The manner in which `std::vector<bool>` is made space efficient (as well as whether it is optimized at all) is implementation defined.
> One potential optimization involves coalescing vector elements such
> that each element occupies a single bit instead of sizeof(bool) bytes.
>
> `std::vector<bool>` behaves similarly to `std::vector`, but in order to
> be space efficient, it:
>
> - Does not necessarily store its elements as a contiguous array.
> - Exposes class `std::vector<bool>::reference` as a method of accessing individual bits. In particular, objects of this class are returned by
>   `operator[]` by value.
> - Does not use `std::allocator_traits::construct` to construct bit values.
> - Does not guarantee that different elements in the same container can be modified concurrently by different threads.

Whether a specialization for `std::vector<bool>` was a good idea is a much discussed issue. See eg [Why isn't vector<bool> a STL container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794569/why-isnt-vectorbool-a-stl-container). Though, the differences mainly show up in generic code, where sometimes one has to add special cases, because `std::vector<bool>` is not like other `std::vector`s in its details.

Comment: *"... possibly ..."* - If I'm reading it correctly, no optimization is guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: @Evg thats how I read it as well. To my understanding the spec is quite liberal such that it does allow the optimization, but not require it. Now I wonder if there is a portable way to figure out if `std::vector<bool>` actually does use 1 bit per element

Comment: @Evg actually the standard is less liberal than cppreference suggests: "Unless described below, all operations have the same requirements and semantics as the primary vector template, except that operations dealing with the bool value type map to bit values in the container storage and allocator_­traits​::​construct is not used to construct these values." see [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/vector.bool#2). I am not fluent in standardese but after reading this I doubt that any implementation does not store bits rather than bools

Comment: Thanks for finding it. I would say this wording is somewhat vague and doesn't define such mapping as mapping between `bool` and exactly one bit.