# C++ vector<bool> error: Taking address of temporary

Tags: c++

I have a function `f` that takes as argument a vector iterator. Inside this function, we need the address of the element that the iterator points to. For `int`-like values, this works fine. However, now I want to use this function on a `std::vector<bool>`, which doesn't compile. The following example should illustrate the situation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename It>
void f(It it) {
    std::cout << "Your iterator starts at " << &(*it) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1(42, 1);
    f(v1.begin()); // <- fine

    std::vector<bool> v2(42, true);
    f(v2.begin()); // <- compilation error
}
```

When I compile this code with `g++ -Wall test.cpp`, the following error is reported:

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void f(It) [with It = std::_Bit_iterator]’:
test.cpp:19:17:   required from here
test.cpp:11:48: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
     std::cout << "Your iterator starts at " << &(*it) << std::endl;
                                                ^~~~~~
```

Removing the line `f(v2.begin());` from the source lets the code compile.

I'd like to understand what's the difference between `int` and `bool` in this case that leads to the observed behavior? Why is `bool` temporary, whereas `int` is not?

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` is a wart. A very ugly wart.  It, and its iterators, don't work like all other iterators work.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794569/why-isnt-vectorbool-a-stl-container

Comment: @LayneBernardo That answers my question. `std::vector<bool>` is not an STL container because of space optimization reasons, so it cannot be used like others.