# `Returning address of local variable` on a C++ templated function with proper return type

Tags: c++

The following code rises the warning:

> warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary

but it makes no sense to me, as the return type is a constant reference of the same type returned by `std::vector::operator[]` and `std::vector::at()`.

Do you have an explanation for it?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class V>
const V &at(const std::vector<V> &p_vec, const std::size_t p_index, const V &p_default) {
    if (p_vec.size() <= p_index) {
        return p_default;
    }
    return p_vec[p_index]; // warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary
}

int main(){
    std::vector<bool> the_vector;

    bool val = at(the_vector, 2, false);

    if (val){
        std::cout << "TRUE" << std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cout << "FALSE" << std::endl;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Sample project: https://godbolt.org/z/KW5qo5YnK

Comment: Is it relevant that this is a template? What is `V` in this case? Please provide a [mcve]!

Comment: If `V` is a `bool`, you [get `std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) which is such an odd duck that it got its own documentation page, and it *does* return a proxy.

Comment: Yes it's a bool

Comment: please read about [mcve]. Dont remove includes, they are needed to make the code compile. If you get the warning on an instantiation of the template, include the instantiation

Comment: Duplicate-ish, if you read between the lines: [Why isn't vector<bool> a STL container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17794569/4581301).

Comment: @user4581301 It make sense now, thanks a lot!

Comment: If you can, consider using a `uint8_t` or a similar to avoid `bool` compression. If you HAVE to use `bool` swap the `vector` for a `std::deque`.

Comment: I've just added a specialized function to handles std::vector<boo>. Please add an Answer, I'll mark it as `Answer`.

Comment: some say `std::vector<bool>` would be broken. Imho its not that broken, but you need to be aware of how it differs from other `std::vector`s, often it doesnt matter, but sometimes it does

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler is right to warn about this, because `std::vector<bool>::operator[]` returns `std::vector<bool>::reference`, which is not a reference to a `bool`. It is an implementation defined proxy type. The proxy can be converted to `bool` and thats the temporary the compiler mentions.

`std::vector<bool>` is specified such that it encourages implementations to pack 8 `bool`s into a single byte. Hence `operator[]` cannot return a reference to `bool`.

You can specialize the function template for `V==bool`, or simply return a value.