# taking address of temporary while accessing address of a element in vector<bool>

Tags: c++

I am getting the warning only while accessing address of element in vector of bool.
For vector of other data types like int i don't get any warning.

eg

```
vector<bool> boolVect;
boolVect.push_back(false);
if (boolVect.size() > 0) {
    cout << &boolVect[0] << endl;
}
```

I get warning "taking address of temporary" at statement "cout << &boolVect[0] << endl;"

Can someone please clarify?

Comment: Try using ``deque<bool>`` instead. It should behave as you expect.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`std::vector<bool>` is broken (see e.g. http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=98 or [Alternative to vector<bool>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670308/alternative-to-vectorbool)).  It's a specialization of `std::vector<T>`, but the individual elements are stored as packed bits.  Therefore, you can't take the address of an individual element.  Therefore, it's really annoying.

Comment: I have a template class. It uses "vector<T> vect", and access address(&vect[i]). I get compile time warning here for T=bool. How can I get rid of this warning if for T=bool, the address is not accessed?

Comment: @Rahul (Long time since you posted, but still...) Can you do a template specialization for bool? You could provide a different implementation for bool that avoids taking the address of an element.

Answer (score 4):

A `vector<bool>` is a template specialization of the standard `vector`. In a normal implementation it saves space, that every `bool` only takes one bit. For convenience you get a temporary object as a reference for your single bit which you otherwise could not address.