# "taking address of temporary" warning

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [taking address of temporary while accessing address of a element in vector<bool>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324699/taking-address-of-temporary-while-accessing-address-of-a-element-in-vectorbool)

I get 'taking address of temporary' warning at line 7 in following piece of code

```
vector<bool> boolVect;
bool x = true;
boolVect.push_back(true);
boolVect.push_back(false);
ofstream fMetaOut("tmp.txt", ios::out);
fMetaOut.write((char* )&x, sizeof(bool));
fMetaOut.write((char* )&boolVect[0], sizeof(bool));
fMetaOut.close();
```

Why do I get this warning at line 7 and not at 6 ??
Both use boolean address. 
How can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: Didn't you have this same issue [five months ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324699/taking-address-of-temporary-while-accessing-address-of-a-element-in-vectorbool)?

Comment: @Blastfurnace there's no way you remembered that... is there? Tell me it's a coincidence you came across his old question!

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: Well, simply click on Rahul's user name, you'll see all his previous questions :)

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: I have a habit of looking at people's profiles and the third question down had the same warning message in the title.

Answer (score 6):

`x` is not an temporary, it is a l-value, an automatic variable which resides on stack.
While, `&boolVect[0]` is not an l-value.
l-value is an entity whose address can be taken, in short a variable whose lifetime is long enough to reside in the memory so that it can be addressed by an name.

**What is problem with `vector<bool>`?? It works fine for `vector<int>`**

The C++ standard library provides a specialization of vector for boolean types.
The goal is optimization, to use less size than a usual implementation of
vector for type `bool`. A usual implementation for `bool` would reserve at least `1` byte for each element. The `vector<bool>` specialization usually uses internally only `1` bit for an element, so it is typically eight times smaller. But this optimization comes with a price:
In C++, the smallest addressable value must have a size of at least `1` byte. Thus, such a specialization of a vector needs special handling for references and iterators.
As a result, a `vector<bool>` does not meet all requirements of other vectors. The behavior you see is one such example, elements of the `vector<bool>` are not a true l-values.

Comment: What is problem with vector<bool>?? It works fine for vector<int>.

Comment: @Rahul: Ellaborated to explain in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike other specialisations of `vector`, `vector<bool>` does not manage an array of `bool` objects. Instead, it manages a packed bitfield.

Since the bits are not individually addressable, `boolVect[0]` is not a reference to a `bool`; it's a (temporary) object of a type that's convertible to `bool`. There is no way to get a reference or pointer to a vector element.

If you want a container of boolean flags that you can take references to, then `vector<char>` or `deque<bool>` might be suitable choices.

Taking the address of `x` is fine, since it is a (non-temporary) `bool` object.