# Converting a vector to an array - Is there a 'standard' way to do this?

Tags: c++, vector

I know you can just do: `&theVector[0]`, but is this standard? Is this behavior *always* guaranteed?

If not, is there a better, less 'hackish' way to do this?

Comment: In C++11 the proper way is `theVector.data()`.

Comment: Note that `&theVector[0]` does not yield an *array*, but rather a *pointer*. Pointers and arrays are different things in the language, with different types. You cannot *convert* a vector to an array in any standard way, although your approach is one standard way of obtaining a *pointer* to the data.

Comment: I wouldn't call this hackish as compatibility with C APIs that use array pointers was a design decision in the STL. The alternative, that sometimes is seen &*theVector.begin(), should not be used.

Comment: @aselle : `&*theVector.begin()` is no better or worse than `&theVector[0]` as long as `theVector` is not a `std::vector<bool>`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, that behavior is guaranteed. Although I can't quote it, the standard guarantees that vector elements are stored consecutively in memory to allow this.

**There is one exception though:**

It will not work for `vector<bool>` because of a template specialization.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_container_%28C%2B%2B%29#Specialization_for_bool

This specialization attempts to save memory by packing `bools` together in a bit-field. However, it breaks some semantics and as such, `&theVector[0]` on a `vector<bool>` will not work.

In any case, `vector<bool>` is widely [considered to be a mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670308/alternative-to-vectorbool) so the alternative is to use `std::deque<bool>` instead.

Comment: I suppose in that case, I would just have to copy it over using `copy` or something?

Comment: There is another exception: if the vector is empty, you can't use the subscript operator on it.

Comment: @JonathanLingle Yes, you can use `std::copy()` to do that.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Ah, yes, of course... since you wouldn't be able to `theVector[0]` in the first place. XD

Comment: Just another random comment: in C++2011 std::vector has data() member returning a pointer to the first element. This also works for empty vectors

Comment: If the vector is empty, is `&theVector[0]`? Surely it is? Of course, it can't be dereferenced. But I still think/hope that it is defined and is equal to `(T*)theVector.begin()`. Anyway, maybe the solution to all this is to use `(+theVector.begin())` instead - unary addition converts things to pointers, IIRC.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: __Point 1:__ `&theVector[0]` is undefined behavior when `theVector.size() == 0`. That means it's defined to nothing. In practice you might get by, but a compiler's optimizers can also play havoc with your code. __Point 2:__ Iterators are not required to support unary +, so there's no guarantee that it does what you want, or anything at all. __Point 3:__ The correct way to get access to the underlying data is currently `theVector.data()`. You'll also get a nice compiler error if you use `std::vector<bool>::data()`, because the underlying array doesn't exist.

Comment: (deleting and replacing my own comment) I somehow thought that iterators have a conversion operator for pointers, but I'm wrong. Now I'm really confused about what to do if the vector is empty, and you don't have `.data()` (because you are pre-C++11)

Answer (score 14):

C++11 provides the `data()` method on `std::vector` which returns a `T*`. This allows you to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> vector = {1,2,3,4,5};
  int* array = vector.data();
  std::cout << array[4] << std::endl; //Prints '5'
}
```

However, doing this (or any of the methods mentioned above) can be dangerous as the pointer could become invalid if the vector is resized. This can be shown with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> vector = {1,2,3,4,5};
  int* array = vector.data();

  vector.resize(100); //This will reserve more memory and move the internal array

  //This _may_ end up taking the place of the old array      
  std::vector<int> other = {6,7,8,9,10}; 

  std::cout << array[4] << std::endl; //_May_ now print '10'
}
```

This could could crash or do just about anything so be careful using this.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using data() method. C++11 provides this method. 
It returns a pointer to the first element in the vector. vector Even if it is empty, we can call this function itself without problems

```
  vector<int>v;
  int *arr = v.data();
```

Answer (score 0):

A less 'hackish' way?   Well you could simply copy :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;



int main()
{ 
    vector<int> vect0r;
    int array[100];

    //Fill vector
    for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) vect0r.push_back( i ) ;

    //Copy vector to array[ ]
    for(  i = 0; i < vect0r.size(); i++) array[i] = vect0r[i];

    //Dispay array[ ]
    for(  i = 0; i < vect0r.size(); i++)  cout<< array[i] <<" \n";

    cout<<" \n";

return 0;
}
```

More here : [How to convert vector to array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923272/how-to-convert-vector-to-array-c)

Comment: `int array[vec.size()];` is not legal C++.

Comment: `MAGIC_NUMBER` coding is technically legal, but a very bad thing. That's not better.