# Using bitwise or equals (|= with a vector

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I can't do the following, compiler says no matching operator in std::vector and I don't think I can overload it. So what are my options, apart from only using the 1 vector to store collision results. I'm trying to be extremely cache friendly and I don't want the same bool reset back to false after its been set to true, hence the or.

```
void CollisionDetection(const vector<Vector2D>& position1, 
                        const vector<Vector2D>& position2,
                        dimension dim1, dimension dim2, 
                        vector<bool>& result1, vector<bool>& result2)
{
    assert(position1.size()==result1.size());
    assert(position2.size()==result2.size());

    for(int i=0;i<position1.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<position2.size();j++)
        {
            result1[i] |= result2[i] |= 
            rectOverlap(position1[1], position2[i], dim1, dim2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the return type of `rectOverlap()`?

Comment: Can you post the definition of `rectOverlap()`?  Also, the definition of `Vector2D` and `dimension`?  I cannot see any problems with the posted part of the code

Comment: just imagine its  result1[i] |= result2[i] |= true; same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector<bool>` is a [specialization of a `std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/). This specialization saves space by using 1 bit for each `bool`, instead of 1 byte.

`std::vector<bool>::operator[]` returns a reference wrapper(in order to allow this space-save optimization), which apparently does not implement `operator|`.

Answer (score 3):

Never use `vector<bool>`.  Yes, I expect bitwise operators to fail miserably on this type.

See e.g. [Alternative to vector<bool>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670308/alternative-to-vectorbool)