# Can I tell the size of an array created with "new type[n]" in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Using C++11, I like to create an array of booleans and immediately clear it

```
bool *mymap = new bool[n];
```

n is variable.

Now, does this already clear the memory occupied by the array? If not, is there a better approach to clear the array than using a loop over all elements, setting each to false individually?

I considered using std:memset(), but that requires me to know the size of the array. Now, beginners might say: Easy, the size is n*sizeof(bool). But I don't buy that. The compiler might decide to pack them differently, even pack them as bits, couldn't it?

So, is there a way to tell the size of the array more cleanly? I imagine there might be a std:arraysize() function that simply returns the space of the allocated array in memory. After all, that information must be maintained at runtime somehow, or a delete invocation wouldn't know how much to release, right?

Comment: What's wrong with `std::vector`?

Comment: @chris std::vector is overkill in my particular use case - using a direct array is faster, too.

Comment: If you create a `std::vector` with a specific size, the overhead is minimal. You should really benchmark it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg std::vector<bool>? I think it is broken.

Comment: @JanHerrmann `std::vector<bool>` doesn't quite work like `std::vector<any_other_type>`, but I wouldn't call it broken.

Comment: *"The compiler might decide to pack them differently, even pack them as bits, couldn't it?"* No. You need to be able to get an address or reference to each individual element.

Comment: I would suggest reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670308/alternative-to-vectorbool

Comment: @jrok: Actually, `std::vector<bool>` is "optimized" and instead of returning a `bool&` it returns a dedicated proxy class :(

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes, I was talking about `new[]`.

Comment: *"But I don't buy that."* - Then that's just the wrong approach. You have to buy it, because that's the ultimate truth. It is really as easy as `n*sizeof(bool)` there is no other magic to it. *"The compiler might decide to pack them differently, even pack them as bits, couldn't it?"* - No, it couldn't. If `new T[N]` wouldn't guarantee a contiguous array of `N` `T`s, the world wouldn't work the way it does anymore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer to the specific question is no, you cannot determine the length of the array pointed at by `mymap`. The language simply provides no mechanism for that.

But if all you want to do is make sure that all the elements of the array are set to `false`, then all you have to do is value initialize it:

```
bool* mymap = new bool[n]();
//                       ^^
```

Unfortunately, this only works for zero-like values for built-in types. There would be no equivalent way to set all the values to `true`.

Comment: Or you can use uniform initialization: `new bool[n] {}`, `new bool[n] {true, false, true}`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do it in a standard way. However, different compilers support different hacks to do it, for example:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) || ( defined(__GNUC__) && defined(_WIN32) )
      // a dirty MSVC and MinGW hack
      size_t Size = _msize( mymap );
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
      // a dirty glibc hack  
      size_t Size = malloc_usable_size( mymap );
#else
   #error Implement for any other compiler
#endif
```

But these are real hacks, so beware.

By the way, `std::vector` can help you to solve your problem within the standard.

Answer (score 4):

No you can't, because it's not actually an array. `mymap` is just a normal pointer to some heap memory, and if you need to know the size you either have to keep track of it yourself or use a standard container such as `std::vector`.

Oh, and if you want a more generic variant of `memset` read about [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill).

Comment: You do realize that the malloc function knows the size of the alloc'd block, right? So why shouldn't the new operator do so, too?

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann `malloc` and `new` don't need to know the size of the allocated block - for example, they could round the size to the next available power of two (or to the size of the next available block of equal or larger size) and store that. Only the `new T[n]` where `T` is a non-POD type is required to store the exact `n`.

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann The *operating system* may keep track of the size, but the compiler most certainly does not. It just asks the operating system for a chunk of memory and then forgets about the size.

Comment: but the compiler must handle the destructor calls for each element, when doing a delete[]. There is a point in Thomas question, after all.

Comment: @CapelliC It doesn't have to if the elements are POD, which they are here.

Comment: The compiler obviously needs to keep track how many elements there are, but the way it does it is completely implementation defined. See [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/num-elems-in-new-array.html). Programmers need to do their own bookkeeping.

Comment: @CapelliC I would argue mine is, since it seems what OP really wants is to make sure the array's elements are all set `false` :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza: seems that user2623967 got your suggestion and jumped on the bandwagon :)

Answer (score 4):

No, the compiler can't decide to pack them except so that the size of the region is `n * sizeof(bool)` - doing it any other way would break the ability to address individual array members as `mymap[x]` (which is the same as `*(mymap + x)`).

In this case, beginners' suggestion is the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
bool *mymap = new bool[n] ();
```

However this sets to `false` and you cannot use such a way to set to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that the compiler decides to pack differently.

Assumption 1: the compiler packs some bits together into one byte. If you take the address of a single element inside the array, it's of type bool. Since the compiler can not (in general) deduct what you will do with this address (e.g. passing it to a function which passes it to a lib, ...), bit-packing inside one byte can't really happen. Otherwise the compiler needs to mask the appropriate bit from its packed region and move it somewhere as a real bool.

Assumption 2: the compiler uses more than sizeof(bool) for one bool value. Highly unlikely - because then sizeof(bool) would simply be greater. Pointer-manipulations are still possible and in case of bit-arrays some other magic logic needs to be implemented.

Assumption 3: the compiler uses different sizes for the different fields of the array - even more unlikely. The administration information required is just too big.

From these 3 thoughts I'd say the simple solution is the best. Just to be sure for now and all the future of your program, write a small unit-test that tests exactly that (e.g. get the address of the first value, cast it to a pointer of a type that has the same sizeof as bool, calculate the address of element n, cast that address back to a pointer of bool, write something there and compare with the array access). Then you'll get a notification if something changes - but I doubt it will.

---

Sidenote - of course the compiler is always able to allocate more memory than required. But still, the array has that size (it's just placed in a larger chunk of memory).

Comment: My thought is this: While a bool might occupy 1 byte, an array might be using word boundaries for each element in order to optimize memory access performance. But then, *a is the same as a[0], and ++a has to step to the next array element. With that, it's probably not allowed for the compiler to pack the array elems with any other size than sizeof(elem).

Comment: if it uses word boundaries to optimize access performance, it would do the same for single values (imagine for example in structs). This then means that sizeof(bool) would be 2 and the assumption n*sizeof(bool) == size of array would hold

Answer (score 2):

In bare bone C++, no it is not possible. However you are encouraged (and really should) consider using a class to manage the memory anyway.

In C++98, you can either use a `boost::scoped_array` or a `std::vector` (though for `bool` you might prefer a `std::vector<char>`).

In C++11, you should consider replacing `boost::scoped_array` by `std::unique_ptr<bool[]>`.

The issue is until then, apart from `std::vector`, none of those know the size of the array they contain; they just handle memory.

In C++14, a new contender appear: [`std::dynarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray). It's a trimmed down version of `std::vector` whose size cannot be resized dynamically. In short, exactly what you want: just the array and its length, no overhead.

If your favorite compiler/toolchain does not support `dynarray` yet you can easily implement it yourself:

```
template <typename T>
class dynarray {
public:
    // methods go here.
private:
    size_t size;
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> array;
}; // class dyn_array
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to std:dynarray. 2014 isn't that far away any more :)