# How can I convert a C++ vector to C-style array?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a class which stores an array and I need to write a method to return a pointer to that array so that other objects can access/modify it.

In an old version of my program, I did that by defining the array in C style. I.e, having a private element `bool* list` and then allocating memory in the constructor (and liberating that in the destructor). The method then was very simple:

```
bool* MyClass::getList() {
    return list;
}
```

Now, I have decided to rewrite the code and use `std::vector<bool>` instead of the classical array. The problem is that I have also modified the above method as:

```
bool* MyClass::getList() {
    return &(list[0]);
}
```

which seems to be the standard way of converting a C++ vector to C array. However, I cannot compile my code, I get the following error:

```
error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<bool>::reference* {aka std::_Bit_reference*}’ to ‘bool*’ in return
```

Could anyone help me out with this and tell me what shall I do?

(I have also read that another alternative is to use `list.data()` as the pointer but this would work only with the newest version of C++ compilers. I am not sure if this is a good idea or not).

Thanks,

Comment: Remember that `std::vector<bool>` is a specialization of `std::vector`, which doesn't work *quite* like a normal vector. See e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool).

Comment: Oh! Thanks for your remark. I guess the problem is that it does not necessarily store its data in a single contiguous chunk of memory.
So what is the solution? (In principle, I am not insisting on using a pointer (`bool*`) as the interface for accessing the list. I just thought this would require least modifications on the other parts of the code).

Comment: You can always allocate a new "array" on the heap, copy from the vector to the array, and return the array. But then the caller have to free the array.

Comment: Thanks, but as the list is quite big I don't want to waste time on copying.

Comment: It's just a [single function call](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy). And it's only going to be noticeable if you have more than several hundred of thousands of entries in the vector.

Comment: Yes, but the function could be called thousands of times and the list contains thousands of entries.

Answer (score 7):

Your course of thinking is right in general and taking a pointer of the first element would have been sufficient. However, [`std::vector<bool>` is not really a vector of `bool`s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_container_%28C++%29#Specialization_for_bool) as it is being implemented as a bit set. There is a general consensus among the C++ Standard Committee and the Library Working Group that `vector<bool>` should be deprecated and subsequently removed from the standard library, while the functionality will be reintroduced under a different name. But for now it is still there.

Getting back to your problem, you cannot really interpret a bitset as array of booleans. Therefore, there are two possible ways to go about this:

1. Replace `std::vector<bool>` with [one of the alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670308/alternative-to-vectorbool) that would give you the right behavior.
2. Convert `std::vector<bool>` to a C array manually when you need it. For example, you can use `size()` to pre-allocate memory, then iterate over a vector and fill our your array.

Hope it helps.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 4):

```
bool* MyClass::getList() {
    return &(list[0]);
}
```

This will work with any type, but `std::vector<bool>` has special implementation, where 8 elements are stored in 1 byte, so it doesn't seem possible to take raw pointer to it.

Answer (score 0):

try string.copy():

```
bool array[100];
std::vector<bool>;
std::copy(vector.begin(), vector.end(), array);
```

Comment: This is very prone to buffer overflow attacks, and the resultant array can't be used as a return value.

Comment: @HampusNilsson That's the reason vectors are better.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector<bool>` uses an internal model where each bool is stored as a single bit. This means it's not a plain C array internally as you would like and you can't convert it to one effortlessly.

Either replace `std::vector<bool>` with `std::deque<bool>` and don't use the deque parts, this will give the expected behaviour.

The other solution is to use a `std::vector<char>` instead and treat the values as bools. This will give the expected behaviour as long as you cast the values properly when accessing it.