# C++ std::vector<bool> gives uninitialized read error using drmemory

Tags: c++, stl, dr-memory

I'm using stl containers in my project and I discovered a weird error that I can't explain. Let's consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<bool> vec;
    vec.resize(5, false);
    std::cout << vec.at(0);
}
```

This outputs 0 as expected, but if I run a memory check with drmemory it discovers an uninitialized read. Can anybody help in understanding this behaviour?

Platform: win32 ;
Compiler: mingw32 - gcc 4.7.2 ;
Drmemory 1.6.0 - build 2

Comment: `vector<bool>` is weird.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::vector<bool>` is a bizarre little thing, using bit twiddling to achieve its goals. I'd be content in this instance to suggest that what you're seeing is just a red herring.

That being said, [you might be better off with some other container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/670308/560648), because [this template specialisation is universally despised](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool).