# Why is the size of the datatype "byte" one byte?

Tags: c#

I've tagged this with [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) but I guess, this will be the same for other programming languages.

Okay why is one **bool** exact one byte but a single bit could already say its **true** or **false**? Because the other bits are used to allocate the object in memory, right?

But when this is true, why is one **byte** (datatype) exact one byte large?

Comment: It's more efficient to deal with multiples of bytes, not bits. Note however, that in C++, `vector<bool>` actually *is* a vector of single bits.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Can I see some evidence for that? I'm actually curious now, because I've not heard of this before now.

Comment: @Jashaszun [Here you go](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/)

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Thank you. I guess I should have done my pre-ask-question-on-SO list, which includes research, before asking you. :)

Comment: @Jashaszun: http://stackoverflow.com/q/670308/103167

Comment: BTW, `bool` in C# is exactly one byte, because it is specified that way.  It's not true in general.  For example, Win32's `BOOL` type is 32 bits.

Comment: @BenVoigt A side remark. Win32 `BOOL` is not really a Boolean type. E.g. C++ expressions like `bVar == TRUE` could lead to application misbehavior.

Comment: _the other bits are used to allocate the object in memory_ __No.__ That's not what the 7 bits are used for. In fact they are __not used at all__. They are lost because 1 byte is the smallest adressable unit of memory in the language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is impossible to allocate memory in units of less than one byte, since a byte is the smallest unit of addressable memory. So a `bool`, although it *could* be represented by only one bit, still takes up one byte of memory. One `byte` is one byte because it *can* be one byte. There's no reason it should be any bigger.

Comment: "_It is impossible to allocate memory in units of less than one byte_" Why? In theory it is possible, it is just implementation choice.

Comment: @AlexD: A byte is typically the smallest addressable unit of memory.  It certainly is the smallest unit that the C++ Standard assumes is addressable.

Comment: Well I guess here comes my outing as newbee:
Does every datatype take its actual size + x bytes for allocation? So one byte takes the actual byte for the datatype + x bytes for allocation?

Comment: Aside from the addressing issue though, allocating an individual byte is almost as hard as allocating an individual bit. Registers are larger, the stack has to be aligned to some large quantity (16 bytes I think?) and dynamic memory allocation usually rounds up and aligns to at least 4 bytes, more often 8.

Comment: @Brettetete No. Every datatype takes its actual size for allocation. It's just that the size of a `bool` is usually 1 byte, and cannot be less.

Comment: @BenVoigt I understand :). But still, C++ has bit fields, right? Generally speaking, we do not need to map machine addresses to variables.

Comment: @delnan, what you are talking about is often related to performance penalties and not necessarily related to addressability. There are some architectures (such as x86) where memory addresses are unique for each memory byte. There are other architectures where memory addresses are unique for words (or dwords)...

Comment: @AlexD: And you can't allocate individual bit fields, only the structure containing them.

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't make sense for a `byte`. A byte represents 8 bit - but `(sizeof(byte) == 1)`. I'm stucking at this point

Comment: @Brettetete `sizeof` returns the size, in bytes (not in bits), of the type or variable.

Comment: @AlexD You can do bit fiddling, but you can't allocate half a byte in any sane environment (though you can, of course, allocate some bytes then use individual bits for different purposes). One of the many reasons for that is that the halves of a byte aren't addressable so the allocator literally has no (standardized) way to communicate which half was allocated for you.

Comment: Well I'm feeling dumb :/
1 byte(datatype) = 1 byte(size)

But where are the bits for allocation? Since 1 byte represents 8 bits there are no "free" bits for allocation

Comment: @Brettetete I'm not sure what you mean. What do you mean by `bits for allocation`?

Comment: @Brettetete, as you noted 1 byte = 8 bits. What other "free" bits are you talking about?

Comment: @elgonzo Indeed, I even opened saying "Aside from the addressing issue ..." ;-) But it's not a performance thing. Bytes don't need to be aligned, the alignment in those cases comes from the allocation mechanism not being designed for allocating individual bytes.

Comment: A `byte` can be 0-255. 0 = 00000000 (8x0). 255 = 11111111 (8x1). So every bit of this byte is needed to represent the actual value. `byte x = 123` needs 8 bits to represent this value. So there are no bits in this byte, which could be used to allocate the variable in memory.

Comment: @Brettetete True... I think you have a misconception about allocation. The allocated object does not need to store where it resides in memory. It is the responsibility of the allocator to keep track of where the object is and free it when appropriate.

Comment: @delnan, aligning data in memory/cache-lines (including stacks) is entirely about avoiding performance penalties imposed by non-aligned memory accesses. On everything else i agree with you :)

Comment: @Brettetete, the variable itself is not stored in memory - the **value** of the variable is stored in memory. Think about the variable representing the storage location of the value it contains...

Comment: @Brettetete I don't know what you think "allocate the variable in memory" means. You asked some entity, called allocator, for a byte of memory. You were then given an address with the promise that this is now *your byte* and you can use it however you want. Whatever bookkeeping the allocator needed to do, it'll happen somewhere else (the allocator manages all the memory, it can carve out some for its own use). Sometimes no bookkeeping is needed. When bookkeeping is needed, it should be included when calculating total memory use, but in no case will it conflict with the memory you allocated.

Comment: @elgonzo That's usually why one aligns an allocation. But there is no need to, and no benefit in, aligning a single byte allocation. When you allocate a byte and it's rounded up and aligned, that happens because your allocator doesn't bother to be (or can't be, in the case of `malloc`) efficient about allocating individual bytes. If you did `new char; new char;` ideally you'd get addresses `0x8000` and `0x8001`, and the following `new int` would yield `0x8004`.

Comment: Just chilling out the comments for an hour. I don't want to discourage your conversation, but please take it to chat!

Answer (score 1):

A bool is one byte because a byte is the smallest unit that can be read from/written to memory.  It is not an 'object' in the sense of an instantiated class, it is a primitive type.  The other bits are in a sense 'wasted' but it simplifies access to the variable by the compiler.

The byte datatype is exactly one byte large because people using it usually want to access the smallest available unit of memory available.  It is also a primitive type so there is no 'object' overhead.

Answer (score 0):

It has to the with the low level semantics of how data is represented in and retrieved from memory due to existing hardware.  If you are interested, you should take a look at the following

-- [Byte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte)

> *The byte /ˈbaɪt/ is a unit of digital information in computing and telecommunications that most commonly consists of eight bits. Historically, the byte was the number of bits used to encode a single character of text in a computer[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) and for this reason it is the smallest addressable unit of memory in many computer architectures.*

-- [Data Structure Alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)

> *Data structure alignment is the way data is arranged and accessed in computer memory. It consists of two separate but related issues: data alignment and data structure padding. When a modern computer reads from or writes to a memory address, it will do this in word sized chunks (e.g. 4 byte chunks on a 32-bit system) or larger.*