# OpenCL and std::vector<bool> incompatibility

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, boolean, opencl

I have a C++ input that is formed as a std::vector and I would like to pass it to my OpenCL kernel (Nvidia platform).

But I keep getting a segmentation fault when the following is executed:

```
queue.enqueueReadBuffer(dev_input, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(bool) * input.size(), &input);
```

Therefore, I tried to copy my `std::vector<bool>` to a `bool[]` and everything worked perfectly. However, the common methods to convert a vector to a C array (`&input[0], input.data())` don't work at all.

Would you have any suggestions either for the ReadBuffer or the fast assignment to a C array?

Thank you!

Comment: `vector<bool>` is "special". See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670308/alternative-to-vectorbool?rq=1

Comment: How does your OpenCL kernel know the memory layout of your input? You're correctly using `sizeof(bool)` so your OpenCL kernel knows how many bytes of input there are, but it has no idea how many elements you pass.

Comment: `sizeof(bool)` is 1 so its actually not needed but additionally I multiply with the `sizeof(bool) * input.size()`. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two problems.

1. Implementations can (optionally) optimize `std::vector<bool>` to be more space efficient, perhaps by packing values into individual bits of memory.  This will not match the layout of an array of `bool`.
2. You can't pass the address of a vector as if it were an array.

   ```
   std::vector<bool> input;
   queue.enqueueReadBuffer(
       dev_input, CL_TRUE, 0,
       sizeof(bool) * input.size(), &input);
   //                               ^^^^^^ wrong
   ```

   If you want to pass a vector as a pointer, you have to either use `input.data()` or something like `&input[0]`.  The reason these don't work is because `std::vector<bool>` is designed to prevent it, because the implementation might be optimized (see point #1).

This is basically a "wart" in the C++ library that has gotten baked in by time.

Fixing this is a pain.

```
// One way to do things...
struct Bool { bool value; }
std::vector<Bool> input;

// Another way to do things...
// (You have to choose the right type here, it depends
// on your platform)
std::vector<int> input;

// Yet another way...
bool *input = new bool[N];
```

That's why this is such a big stinking wart.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! When I use either of  `input.data()` or `&input[0]` I get a "invalid use of void expression" error. So, there is no way to use it directly?

Comment: Right.  You will have to use some other data structure besides `std::vector<bool>`.  I've expanded the answer.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use the [`copy()`](http://kylelutz.github.io/compute/boost/compute/copy.html) algorithm provided by [Boost.Compute](https://github.com/kylelutz/compute).

Basically, you can do something like this:

```
// vector of bools on the host
std::vector<bool> host_vec = { ... };

// vector of bools on the device (each represented with a uchar)
boost::compute::vector<uchar_> gpu_vec(host_vec.size(), ctx);

// copy bool values on host to the device
boost::compute::copy(host_vec.begin(), host_vec.end(), gpu_vec.begin(), queue);
```

And Boost.Compute will take care of copying the data to the compute device correctly.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing to add:

Type `bool` within OpenCL kernel isn't guaranteed to match any of the host-side types. Generally, you should avoid using boolean types in Host-Device interconnection.