# Is there a standard way to replace a C-style bool array?

Tags: c++, arrays, boolean, std

In this piece of code

```
void legacyFunction(int length, bool *bitset)
{
    // stuff, lots of stuff
}

int main()
{
    int somenumber = 6;
    // somenumber is set to some value here

    bool *isBitXSet = new bool[somenumber];
    // initialisation of isBitXSet.

    legacyFunction(somenumber, isBitXSet);

    delete[] isBitXSet;
    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to replace `bool *isBitXSet = new bool[somenumber];` by something like

```
std::vector<bool> isBitXset(somenumber, false);
```

But I cannot do

```
legacyFunction(somenumber, isBitXSet.data());
```

because `data()` doesn't exist for `std::vector<bool>`. And I cannot change the interface of `legacyFunction()`.

Is there a good alternative to the C-style bool array?

Comment: Note that the missing `data()` member function is not the only problem. `std::vector<bool>` is a specialization that may provide a more space-efficient implementation. So the elements of `vector<bool>` and a C-style `bool` array may not overlap.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative to vector<bool>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670308/alternative-to-vectorbool)

Comment: @moooeeeep Yeah, right, sorry. Normally I would delete the question by myself. But I like the answer given by Vittorio Romeo much more than any of those answers from 2009.

Comment: No need to worry. I just wanted to have them linked and thought they might be related close enough to have them as duplicate. Others might disagree.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`std::unique_ptr<T[]>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique):

```
int main()
{
    int somenumber = 6;
    // somenumber is set to some value here

    auto isBitXSet = std::make_unique<bool[]>(somenumber);    
    // initialisation of isBitXSet.

    legacyFunction(somenumber, isBitXSet.get());

    return 0;
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can "trick" `std::vector` by creating your own `bool` wrapper:

```
struct my_bool { bool _b; };
std::vector<my_bool> v; // will not use `vector<bool>` specialization
```

---

If you know the size of your array at compile-time, consider using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: Isn't `std::array` also a possibility?

Comment: @Rakete1111: not if `somenumber` is a run-time value, as in the example.

Comment: Nice answer! In your second example: How would I apply this to make the function call? Like this `legacyFunction(somenumber, reinterpret_cast<bool*>(v.data()));`?

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi: that will probably work but I am unsure about its safety and standard-compliance. Only use that after proper research. I would suggest going with `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi How about `legacyFunction(somenumber, &v[0]);` ?

Comment: Shoot.. can't edit, I'm a little too late.  But my previous comment works for the unique_ptr case, but not the vector of struct case.  (Not without casting)