# Why does std::vector<bool> have no .data()?

Tags: c++, memory, vector, boolean, contiguous

The specialisation of `std::vector<bool>`, as specified in C++11 23.3.7/1, doesn't declare a `data()` member (e.g. mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568986/what-happens-when-you-call-data-on-a-stdvectorbool) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46115237/is-there-a-standard-way-to-replace-a-c-style-bool-array)).

The question is: Why does a `std::vector<bool>` have no `.data()`? This is the very same question as why is a vector of `bool`s not stored contiguously in memory. What are the benefits in not doing so?

Why can a pointer to an array of `bool`s not be returned?

Comment: `vector<bool>` allow to have space optimization by packing several bool in one byte. `data()` would remove that benefit.

Comment: The benefit is that you use 8 times less memory. The downside is that you mess with people's expectations. It has more or less been concluded that the downside outweighs the benefit.

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` is a bit like inviting your mother in law to live with you. It might seem like a good idea at the time, but you'll eventually regret the whole idea. Luckily I can only credit myself with one of these transgressions.

Comment: @Bathsheba you designed and implemented std::vector<bool> ?   You should be ashamed, and I'm reporting you to your mother in law.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> Why does a std::vector have no .data()?

Because [`std::vector<bool>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/) stores multiple values in 1 byte.

Think about it like a compressed storage system, where every boolean value needs 1 bit. So, instead of having one element per memory block (one element per array cell), the memory layout may look like this:

[image]

Assuming that you want to index a block to get a value, how would you use operator `[]`? It can't return `bool&` (since it will return one byte, which stores more than one `bools`), thus you couldn't assign a `bool*` to it. In other words `bool *bool_ptr =&v[0];` is *not* valid code, and would result in a compilation error.

Moreover, a correct implementation might not have that specialization and don't do the memory optimization (compression). So `data()` would have to copy to the expected return type depending of implementation (or standard should force optimization instead of just allowing it).

> Why can a pointer to an array of bools not be returned?

Because `std::vector<bool>` is *not* stored as an array of bools, thus no pointer can be returned in a straightforward way. It could do that by copying the data to an array and return that array, but it's a design choice not to do that (if they did, I would think that this works as the `data()` for all containers, which would be misleading).

> What are the benefits in not doing so?

Memory optimization.

Usually 8 times less memory usage, since it stores multiple bits in a single byte. To be exact, [`CHAR_BIT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3200969/2411320) times less.

Comment: BTW, correct implementation might don't have that specialization and don't do the memory optimization. so `data()` would have to copy to the expected return type depending of implementation. (or standard should force optimization instead of just allowing it).

Comment: I'm ok with that.BTW, *"layout looks like this:"* -> **may** looks like. as it is implementation specific (in particular "endianess")

Comment: @Bathsheba: I don't think the Standard guarantees maximum packing. It would be allowed to pack 8 bits per byte, regardless of CHAR_BIT.

Comment: IMO, getting rid of bool in your abstract and converting true|false type to another is the most logical course of action if you use vectors with templates.  otherwise the code quality becomes worse.  Bool it is.