# Why does the disjunction assignment operator |= not work with vectors of bools?

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

If I have a `vector<bool> vec_bool` then I cannot modify the contents of the vector using the `|=` assignment operator. That is, the lines

```
vec_bool[0] |= true;
vec_bool[0] |= vec_bool[1];
```

give compiler errors, while the lines

```
bool a = false;
a |= true;
a |= vec_bool[0];
vec_bool[0] = vec_bool[0] | vec_bool[1];
vec_bool[0] = vec_bool[0] || vec_bool[1];

vector<int> vec_int(3);
vec_int[0] |= vec_int[1];
```

do not. What is the reason for this?

The error given (by gcc) is:

> test.cpp:21:17: error: no match for ‘operator|=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector::reference {aka std::_Bit_reference}’ and ‘bool’)

Comment: You have to remember that [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) is not an *ordinary* vector. It's not an actual vector of `bool`, but more like a vector of bits, whose implementation is not specified by the C++ specification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does std::vector<bool> has no .data()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46115669/why-does-stdvectorbool-has-no-data)

Comment: You can take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool for more information about it

Comment: @GauravSehgal related, but not a duplicate. The same underlying cause, but very different question/goal.

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that [std::array<bool>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) has not this kind of optimization, so it behaves different ([...]`This container is an aggregate type with the same semantics as a struct holding a C-style array T[N] as its only non-static data member.`[...]). However you lose the ability to resize it. For [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acc6abad754046cc).

Comment: To paraphrase Scott Meyers *"There are two problems with `vector<bool>`.  It is not a vector.  It does not store `bool`s"*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `reference` returned from `operator[]` of `std::vector<bool>` is not an alias for `bool&`, as it is for the primary specialization of `std::vector`. It is rather specified by the [C++ standard as this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/vector.bool):

```
// bit reference:
class reference {
  friend class vector;
  reference() noexcept;
public:
  ~reference();
  operator bool() const noexcept;
  reference& operator=(const bool x) noexcept;
  reference& operator=(const reference& x) noexcept;
  void flip() noexcept;     // flips the bit
};
```

And as you can see, there is no `operator |=` declared. So you can't apply it on the reference returned from `vec_bool[0]`.

The reason that `vec_bool[0] = vec_bool[0] | vec_bool[1];` works is that there *are* overloads above that facilitate it. `operator bool()` converts the two operands of the built-in `|` into `bool` values. And then the assignment operator of `reference` assigns the result back to `vec_bool[0]`.

As specified by the C++ standard, `std::vector<bool>` isn't a particularly good abstraction, IMO.

Comment: Thank you! Could you perhaps tell me if `vector<bool>` is the only type of vector that deviates from the 'standard' implementation of the vector type?

Comment: @MeesdeVries - It's the only one that the C++ standard mandates to deviate from the primary declaration. All others you can assume to be of the primary template.

Comment: ... which is to say, others may be specialized for performance reasons, but you can't detect that in portable code.