# Why does std::foreach not work with a std::vector<bool>?

Tags: c++, vector, foreach, boolean

I have the following code snippet, which takes the `std::vector<int> list` and writes a zero in all vector elements. This example is working perfectly fine.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main () {
    std::vector<int> list {1, 1, 2};
    auto reset = [](int & element){element = 0;};

    auto print = [](int element) {std::cout << element << " ";};
    std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), reset);
    std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), print);
}
```

If I take change the type of the vector from `int` to `bool`, the code will not compile.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main () {
    std::vector<bool> list {true, true, false};
    auto reset = [](bool & element){element = false;};

    auto print = [](int element) {std::cout << element << " ";};
    std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), reset);
    std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), print);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/2EntgX

I don't understand the compiler error message:

> /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h:3884:2: error: no matching function for call to object of type '(lambda at
>   :7:18)'
>
> ```
>     __f(*__first);
>
>     ^~~
> ```
>
> :10:10: note: in instantiation of function template
>   specialization 'std::for_each:7:18)>' requested here
>
> ```
> std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(),reset);
>
>      ^
> ```
>
> :7:18: note: candidate function not viable: no known
>   conversion from 'std::_Bit_iterator::reference' (aka
>   'std::_Bit_reference') to 'bool &' for 1st argument
>
> ```
> auto reset = [](bool & element){element = false;};
>
>              ^
> ```
>
> :7:18: note: conversion candidate of type 'void (*)(bool &)'

Why does `std::foreach` work with a `std::vector<int>`, but does not work with a `std::vector<bool>`?

Is the memory optimisation of an `std::vector<bool>` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46115669/why-does-stdvectorbool-have-no-data) ) part of the answer?

Comment: Iterator type of `std::vector<bool>` doesn't return `bool&` on dereference. Rather, it returns a proxy object. Use `auto&` instead of `bool&` to get the proxy.

Comment: @Incomputable: Please don't put answers in the comments section.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Reason

The problem stems from the fact that dereferencing an iterator that came from [`std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool)  doesn't return `bool&`, but rather a proxy object. Thus, [it is not regarded as stl container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794569/why-is-vectorbool-not-a-stl-container) (thanks to @KillzoneKid).

### Fix

Use `auto element` in the parameter list. In general, if you don't care about the type, use `auto&&` in the lambda parameter list.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main () {
    std::vector<bool> list {true, true, false};
    auto reset = [](auto && element){element = false;};

    auto print = [](int element) {std::cout<< element << " ";};
    std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(),reset);
    std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(),print);

}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hSV4OrF7L4l9fmly).

Trying to use `auto&` will [trigger compilation error again](https://godbolt.org/g/e1Rrtz), as the proxy returned is not lvalue, but rvalue. Thus, `auto&&` has even more benefits than usual.

Comment: Cool. How exactly does type inference work here?

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I'm not sure about it, but since `std::vector<bool>::reference` is user-defined type, dereferencing it will return non-reference, thus the copying of the proxy will cause no harm.