# how to complement the values of std::vector<bool> using range for loop taking element by reference

Tags: c++

I need to complement the values of `std::vector<bool>`. So I thought of using range for loop taking elements by reference. But the compiler is giving me the below error

```
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'std::_Bit_reference&' to an rvalue of type 'std::_Bit_iterator::reference'
   13 |     for (auto& bit : rep)
```

This is my sample code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<bool> rep;
    rep.push_back(true);
    rep.push_back(false);
    rep.push_back(true);
    rep.push_back(false);
    rep.push_back(true);
    rep.push_back(false);

    for (auto& bit : rep)
        bit = !bit;
}
```

Comment: This was probably a trick question, if you found it as challenge somewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does std::vector<bool> have no .data()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46115669/why-does-stdvectorbool-have-no-data)

Comment: I would recommend to use `std::bitset` if possible. I think `std::vector<bool>` is design mistake that they have to keep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can bind them (the returned proxy object) to rvalue reference

```
for (auto&& bit : rep)
   bit = !bit;
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/KdG7PsP1q)

Comment: But would inverting the bits work as intended?

Comment: @Sebastian yes it'd work https://godbolt.org/z/fWdaKddh6

Comment: actually you can probably also catch the proxy object by value. (I'm not  sure standard require them to be copyable though)

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [`std::vector<bool>::flip`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/flip) to toggle every value  in the `vector<bool>`.

```
std::vector<bool> rep{true, false, true, false, true, false};

for(bool v: rep)
    std::cout << v; 
std::cout << '\n';
rep.flip();
for(bool v: rep)
    std::cout << v;
```

Output:

```
101010
010101
```

[`std::vector<bool>::reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference) is the proxy type stored underneath which also has flip function `std::vector<bool>::reference::flip`.

```
for(auto&& v: rep)
    v.flip();
```