# Creating 2-D Boolean Vector with False value

Tags: c++, vector

i want too create a 2-D vector of Boolean type with Size n x n . but i don't want to use two for loop to assign false to every index instead of assign directly while creating this vector.
syntax is:- `vector<vector<bool>> V(n,false)`

but it gives me error

Comment: Use `std::fill`

Answer (score 2):

There is a constructor that takes a count and an element, but `false` is not a `std::vector<bool>`. You want

```
std::vector<std::vector<bool>> V(n, std::vector<bool>(n,false)  );
                               //   |---- inner vectors  ----|
```

Two disclaimer:

Use `std::vector<bool>` with caution. It is not like other `std::vector`s  (see eg [Alternative to vector<bool>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670308/alternative-to-vectorbool)).

A vector of vectors is rarely the best data structure. The power of a `std::vector` is its data locality, however a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` does not have this feature (only elements of the inner vectors are contiguous).

Comment: Indeed; `std::vector<bool>` of size _n×n_ would be far superior.

Answer (score 1):

`vector<vector> V(n,false)` this gives an error because you are not declaring size of each v[i] thus, it can not assign each of v[i][j] to false.

you can use  vector<vector> v(n, vector (n, false));

Code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<vector<bool>> v(n, vector<bool> (n, false));

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<v[i].size();j++)
        {
            cout<<v[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<'\n';
    }
}
```

Ans:

```
n=5
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```